# How to determine the current iPhone/device model?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Is there a way to get the device model name (iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPhone 5S, etc) in Swift?

I know there is a property named `UIDevice.currentDevice().model` but it only returns device type (iPod touch, iPhone, iPad, iPhone Simulator, etc).

I also know it can be done easily in Objective-C with this method:

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);

NSString* deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But I'm developing my iPhone app in Swift so could someone please help me with the equivalent way to solve this in Swift?

Comment: Do it in Objective C and just call that from Swift.

Comment: @jww CarPlay runs on the iOS device. iOS just uses the display, touch inputs, speakers etc. from the car (stereo), everything is executed on the iOS device, not on the car (stereo).

Comment: Xamarin iOS: https://github.com/dannycabrera/Get-iOS-Model

Answer (score 1266, accepted):

I made this "pure Swift" extension on [`UIDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDevice).

If you are looking for a more elegant solution you can use [my µ-framework `DeviceKit`](https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit) published on GitHub (also available via CocoaPods, Carthage and Swift Package Manager).

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

public extension UIDevice {

    static let modelName: String = {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }

        func mapToDevice(identifier: String) -> String { // swiftlint:disable:this cyclomatic_complexity
            #if os(iOS)
            switch identifier {
            case "iPod5,1":                                       return "iPod touch (5th generation)"
            case "iPod7,1":                                       return "iPod touch (6th generation)"
            case "iPod9,1":                                       return "iPod touch (7th generation)"
            case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":           return "iPhone 4"
            case "iPhone4,1":                                     return "iPhone 4s"
            case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                        return "iPhone 5"
            case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                        return "iPhone 5c"
            case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                        return "iPhone 5s"
            case "iPhone7,2":                                     return "iPhone 6"
            case "iPhone7,1":                                     return "iPhone 6 Plus"
            case "iPhone8,1":                                     return "iPhone 6s"
            case "iPhone8,2":                                     return "iPhone 6s Plus"
            case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3":                        return "iPhone 7"
            case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4":                        return "iPhone 7 Plus"
            case "iPhone10,1", "iPhone10,4":                      return "iPhone 8"
            case "iPhone10,2", "iPhone10,5":                      return "iPhone 8 Plus"
            case "iPhone10,3", "iPhone10,6":                      return "iPhone X"
            case "iPhone11,2":                                    return "iPhone XS"
            case "iPhone11,4", "iPhone11,6":                      return "iPhone XS Max"
            case "iPhone11,8":                                    return "iPhone XR"
            case "iPhone12,1":                                    return "iPhone 11"
            case "iPhone12,3":                                    return "iPhone 11 Pro"
            case "iPhone12,5":                                    return "iPhone 11 Pro Max"
            case "iPhone13,1":                                    return "iPhone 12 mini"
            case "iPhone13,2":                                    return "iPhone 12"
            case "iPhone13,3":                                    return "iPhone 12 Pro"
            case "iPhone13,4":                                    return "iPhone 12 Pro Max"
            case "iPhone14,4":                                    return "iPhone 13 mini"
            case "iPhone14,5":                                    return "iPhone 13"
            case "iPhone14,2":                                    return "iPhone 13 Pro"
            case "iPhone14,3":                                    return "iPhone 13 Pro Max"
            case "iPhone14,7":                                    return "iPhone 14"
            case "iPhone14,8":                                    return "iPhone 14 Plus"
            case "iPhone15,2":                                    return "iPhone 14 Pro"
            case "iPhone15,3":                                    return "iPhone 14 Pro Max"
            case "iPhone15,4":                                    return "iPhone 15"
            case "iPhone15,5":                                    return "iPhone 15 Plus"
            case "iPhone16,1":                                    return "iPhone 15 Pro"
            case "iPhone16,2":                                    return "iPhone 15 Pro Max"
            case "iPhone8,4":                                     return "iPhone SE"
            case "iPhone12,8":                                    return "iPhone SE (2nd generation)"
            case "iPhone14,6":                                    return "iPhone SE (3rd generation)"
            case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":      return "iPad 2"
            case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":                 return "iPad (3rd generation)"
            case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":                 return "iPad (4th generation)"
            case "iPad6,11", "iPad6,12":                          return "iPad (5th generation)"
            case "iPad7,5", "iPad7,6":                            return "iPad (6th generation)"
            case "iPad7,11", "iPad7,12":                          return "iPad (7th generation)"
            case "iPad11,6", "iPad11,7":                          return "iPad (8th generation)"
            case "iPad12,1", "iPad12,2":                          return "iPad (9th generation)"
            case "iPad13,18", "iPad13,19":                        return "iPad (10th generation)"
            case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":                 return "iPad Air"
            case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                            return "iPad Air 2"
            case "iPad11,3", "iPad11,4":                          return "iPad Air (3rd generation)"
            case "iPad13,1", "iPad13,2":                          return "iPad Air (4th generation)"
            case "iPad13,16", "iPad13,17":                        return "iPad Air (5th generation)"
            case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":                 return "iPad mini"
            case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":                 return "iPad mini 2"
            case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":                 return "iPad mini 3"
            case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                            return "iPad mini 4"
            case "iPad11,1", "iPad11,2":                          return "iPad mini (5th generation)"
            case "iPad14,1", "iPad14,2":                          return "iPad mini (6th generation)"
            case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4":                            return "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"
            case "iPad7,3", "iPad7,4":                            return "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)"
            case "iPad8,1", "iPad8,2", "iPad8,3", "iPad8,4":      return "iPad Pro (11-inch) (1st generation)"
            case "iPad8,9", "iPad8,10":                           return "iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation)"
            case "iPad13,4", "iPad13,5", "iPad13,6", "iPad13,7":  return "iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation)"
            case "iPad14,3", "iPad14,4":                          return "iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation)"
            case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":                            return "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (1st generation)"
            case "iPad7,1", "iPad7,2":                            return "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)"
            case "iPad8,5", "iPad8,6", "iPad8,7", "iPad8,8":      return "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)"
            case "iPad8,11", "iPad8,12":                          return "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)"
            case "iPad13,8", "iPad13,9", "iPad13,10", "iPad13,11":return "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)"
            case "iPad14,5", "iPad14,6":                          return "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation)"
            case "AppleTV5,3":                                    return "Apple TV"
            case "AppleTV6,2":                                    return "Apple TV 4K"
            case "AudioAccessory1,1":                             return "HomePod"
            case "AudioAccessory5,1":                             return "HomePod mini"
            case "i386", "x86_64", "arm64":                       return "Simulator \(mapToDevice(identifier: ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] ?? "iOS"))"
            default:                                              return identifier
            }
            #elseif os(tvOS)
            switch identifier {
            case "AppleTV5,3": return "Apple TV 4"
            case "AppleTV6,2", "AppleTV11,1", "AppleTV14,1": return "Apple TV 4K"
            case "i386", "x86_64": return "Simulator \(mapToDevice(identifier: ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] ?? "tvOS"))"
            default: return identifier
            }
            #elseif os(visionOS)
            switch identifier {
            case "RealityDevice14,1": return "Apple Vision Pro"
            default: return identifier
            }
            #endif
        }

        return mapToDevice(identifier: identifier)
    }()

}
```

You call it like this:

```
let modelName = UIDevice.modelName
```

For real devices it returns e.g. "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)", for simulators it returns e.g. "Simulator iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)"

Here's the model references:

- https://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models
- https://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/BORD

Comment: An older revision of this is [used in Australia's CovidSafe app](https://github.com/AU-COVIDSafe/mobile-ios/blob/master/CovidSafe/DeviceIdentifier.swift#L5) copied exactly, even the `swiftlint:disable:this` despite the project not even using SwiftLint. For some reason, I find it a bit funny that a government app uses copied and pasted Stack Overflow code (even though the majority of apps probably already do that).

Comment: This solution is not sustainable: you would have to create a new release of your app each time there is a new model.

Comment: Family(iPhone7) has Id(iPhone9,1, iPhone9,3) which has Model: 9,1 - A1660, A1779, A1780 and 9,3 - A1778. Find it here: https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=iPhone9%2C3+%7C%7C+iPhone9%2C1

Comment: every year for last 5 years at least I go to this page and update new data. Thanks so much to author for keeping mapping table up to date!

Comment: I have used this code deployed in an app on the store for over 3 years. much thanks!

Comment: Looks like the first generation of Vision Pro is identified as `RealityDevice14,1`.

Answer (score 264):

## Swift 5.x, both device & simulator WITH ENUMS(to check whatever group or model you prefer)

---

## - Updated to September 2023 -

*(always checked and updated!)*

with the last: **iPad 10th generation**, **iPhone 15 ALL VERSIONS, iPhone SE 3rd generation 2022**, **iPad Air 5th generation**, **iPhone 13 (all models)**, **iPad 9th generation 2021**, **iPad mini 6th generation 2021**, **Apple Watch Series 7**, iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation), iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) and Apple TV 4K (2nd generation) , (updates also for **all iPods, Apple Watches and Apple TVs**)

This method detects the correct model even if it's a simulator. (**The exact name for the simulator device model running in your simulator**)

### **With this answer you can check multiple device in few lines thanks to the  enums**

example:

```
var myDefaultFontSize: CGFloat = 26.0
switch UIDevice().type {
    case .iPhoneSE, .iPhone5, .iPhone5S: print("default value")
    case .iPhone6, .iPhone7, .iPhone8, .iPhone6S, .iPhoneX: myDefaultFontSize += 4
    default: break
}
```

This is the code:

```
public enum Model : String {

//Simulator
case simulator     = "simulator/sandbox",

//iPod
iPod1              = "iPod 1",
iPod2              = "iPod 2",
iPod3              = "iPod 3",
iPod4              = "iPod 4",
iPod5              = "iPod 5",
iPod6              = "iPod 6",
iPod7              = "iPod 7",

//iPad
iPad2              = "iPad 2",
iPad3              = "iPad 3",
iPad4              = "iPad 4",
iPadAir            = "iPad Air ",
iPadAir2           = "iPad Air 2",
iPadAir3           = "iPad Air 3",
iPadAir4           = "iPad Air 4",
iPadAir5           = "iPad Air 5",
iPad5              = "iPad 5", //iPad 2017
iPad6              = "iPad 6", //iPad 2018
iPad7              = "iPad 7", //iPad 2019
iPad8              = "iPad 8", //iPad 2020
iPad9              = "iPad 9", //iPad 2021
iPad10             = "iPad 10", //iPad 2022

//iPad Mini
iPadMini           = "iPad Mini",
iPadMini2          = "iPad Mini 2",
iPadMini3          = "iPad Mini 3",
iPadMini4          = "iPad Mini 4",
iPadMini5          = "iPad Mini 5",
iPadMini6          = "iPad Mini 6",

//iPad Pro
iPadPro9_7         = "iPad Pro 9.7\"",
iPadPro10_5        = "iPad Pro 10.5\"",
iPadPro11          = "iPad Pro 11\"",
iPadPro2_11        = "iPad Pro 11\" 2nd gen",
iPadPro3_11        = "iPad Pro 11\" 3rd gen",
iPadPro12_9        = "iPad Pro 12.9\"",
iPadPro2_12_9      = "iPad Pro 2 12.9\"",
iPadPro3_12_9      = "iPad Pro 3 12.9\"",
iPadPro4_12_9      = "iPad Pro 4 12.9\"",
iPadPro5_12_9      = "iPad Pro 5 12.9\"",

//iPhone
iPhone4            = "iPhone 4",
iPhone4S           = "iPhone 4S",
iPhone5            = "iPhone 5",
iPhone5S           = "iPhone 5S",
iPhone5C           = "iPhone 5C",
iPhone6            = "iPhone 6",
iPhone6Plus        = "iPhone 6 Plus",
iPhone6S           = "iPhone 6S",
iPhone6SPlus       = "iPhone 6S Plus",
iPhoneSE           = "iPhone SE",
iPhone7            = "iPhone 7",
iPhone7Plus        = "iPhone 7 Plus",
iPhone8            = "iPhone 8",
iPhone8Plus        = "iPhone 8 Plus",
iPhoneX            = "iPhone X",
iPhoneXS           = "iPhone XS",
iPhoneXSMax        = "iPhone XS Max",
iPhoneXR           = "iPhone XR",
iPhone11           = "iPhone 11",
iPhone11Pro        = "iPhone 11 Pro",
iPhone11ProMax     = "iPhone 11 Pro Max",
iPhoneSE2          = "iPhone SE 2nd gen",
iPhone12Mini       = "iPhone 12 Mini",
iPhone12           = "iPhone 12",
iPhone12Pro        = "iPhone 12 Pro",
iPhone12ProMax     = "iPhone 12 Pro Max",
iPhone13Mini       = "iPhone 13 Mini",
iPhone13           = "iPhone 13",
iPhone13Pro        = "iPhone 13 Pro",
iPhone13ProMax     = "iPhone 13 Pro Max",
iPhoneSE3          = "iPhone SE 3nd gen",
iPhone14           = "iPhone 14",
iPhone14Plus       = "iPhone 14 Plus",
iPhone14Pro        = "iPhone 14 Pro",
iPhone14ProMax     = "iPhone 14 Pro Max",
iPhone15           = "iPhone 15",
iPhone15Plus       = "iPhone 15 Plus",
iPhone15Pro        = "iPhone 15 Pro",
iPhone15ProMax     = "iPhone 15 Pro Max",

// Apple Watch
AppleWatch1         = "Apple Watch 1gen",
AppleWatchS1        = "Apple Watch Series 1",
AppleWatchS2        = "Apple Watch Series 2",
AppleWatchS3        = "Apple Watch Series 3",
AppleWatchS4        = "Apple Watch Series 4",
AppleWatchS5        = "Apple Watch Series 5",
AppleWatchSE        = "Apple Watch Special Edition",
AppleWatchS6        = "Apple Watch Series 6",
AppleWatchS7        = "Apple Watch Series 7",

//Apple TV
AppleTV1           = "Apple TV 1gen",
AppleTV2           = "Apple TV 2gen",
AppleTV3           = "Apple TV 3gen",
AppleTV4           = "Apple TV 4gen",
AppleTV_4K         = "Apple TV 4K",
AppleTV2_4K        = "Apple TV 4K 2gen",
AppleTV3_4K        = "Apple TV 4K 3gen",

unrecognized       = "?unrecognized?"
}

// #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
// MARK: UIDevice extensions
// #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#

    public extension UIDevice {
    
    var type: Model {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let modelCode = withUnsafePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
                ptr in String.init(validatingUTF8: ptr)
            }
        }
    
        let modelMap : [String: Model] = [
    
            //Simulator
            "i386"      : .simulator,
            "x86_64"    : .simulator,
    
            //iPod
            "iPod1,1"   : .iPod1,
            "iPod2,1"   : .iPod2,
            "iPod3,1"   : .iPod3,
            "iPod4,1"   : .iPod4,
            "iPod5,1"   : .iPod5,
            "iPod7,1"   : .iPod6,
            "iPod9,1"   : .iPod7,
    
            //iPad
            "iPad2,1"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,2"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,3"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,4"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad3,1"   : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,2"   : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,3"   : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,4"   : .iPad4,
            "iPad3,5"   : .iPad4,
            "iPad3,6"   : .iPad4,
            "iPad6,11"  : .iPad5, //iPad 2017
            "iPad6,12"  : .iPad5,
            "iPad7,5"   : .iPad6, //iPad 2018
            "iPad7,6"   : .iPad6,
            "iPad7,11"  : .iPad7, //iPad 2019
            "iPad7,12"  : .iPad7,
            "iPad11,6"  : .iPad8, //iPad 2020
            "iPad11,7"  : .iPad8,
            "iPad12,1"  : .iPad9, //iPad 2021
            "iPad12,2"  : .iPad9,
            "iPad13,18" : .iPad10,
            "iPad13,19" : .iPad10,
    
            //iPad Mini
            "iPad2,5"   : .iPadMini,
            "iPad2,6"   : .iPadMini,
            "iPad2,7"   : .iPadMini,
            "iPad4,4"   : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,5"   : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,6"   : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,7"   : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad4,8"   : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad4,9"   : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad5,1"   : .iPadMini4,
            "iPad5,2"   : .iPadMini4,
            "iPad11,1"  : .iPadMini5,
            "iPad11,2"  : .iPadMini5,
            "iPad14,1"  : .iPadMini6,
            "iPad14,2"  : .iPadMini6,
    
            //iPad Pro
            "iPad6,3"   : .iPadPro9_7,
            "iPad6,4"   : .iPadPro9_7,
            "iPad7,3"   : .iPadPro10_5,
            "iPad7,4"   : .iPadPro10_5,
            "iPad6,7"   : .iPadPro12_9,
            "iPad6,8"   : .iPadPro12_9,
            "iPad7,1"   : .iPadPro2_12_9,
            "iPad7,2"   : .iPadPro2_12_9,
            "iPad8,1"   : .iPadPro11,
            "iPad8,2"   : .iPadPro11,
            "iPad8,3"   : .iPadPro11,
            "iPad8,4"   : .iPadPro11,
            "iPad8,9"   : .iPadPro2_11,
            "iPad8,10"  : .iPadPro2_11,
            "iPad13,4"  : .iPadPro3_11,
            "iPad13,5"  : .iPadPro3_11,
            "iPad13,6"  : .iPadPro3_11,
            "iPad13,7"  : .iPadPro3_11,
            "iPad8,5"   : .iPadPro3_12_9,
            "iPad8,6"   : .iPadPro3_12_9,
            "iPad8,7"   : .iPadPro3_12_9,
            "iPad8,8"   : .iPadPro3_12_9,
            "iPad8,11"  : .iPadPro4_12_9,
            "iPad8,12"  : .iPadPro4_12_9,
            "iPad13,8"  : .iPadPro5_12_9,
            "iPad13,9"  : .iPadPro5_12_9,
            "iPad13,10" : .iPadPro5_12_9,
            "iPad13,11" : .iPadPro5_12_9,
    
            //iPad Air
            "iPad4,1"   : .iPadAir,
            "iPad4,2"   : .iPadAir,
            "iPad4,3"   : .iPadAir,
            "iPad5,3"   : .iPadAir2,
            "iPad5,4"   : .iPadAir2,
            "iPad11,3"  : .iPadAir3,
            "iPad11,4"  : .iPadAir3,
            "iPad13,1"  : .iPadAir4,
            "iPad13,2"  : .iPadAir4,
            "iPad13,16" : .iPadAir5,
            "iPad13,17" : .iPadAir5,
    
            //iPhone
            "iPhone3,1" : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone3,2" : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone3,3" : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone4,1" : .iPhone4S,
            "iPhone5,1" : .iPhone5,
            "iPhone5,2" : .iPhone5,
            "iPhone5,3" : .iPhone5C,
            "iPhone5,4" : .iPhone5C,
            "iPhone6,1" : .iPhone5S,
            "iPhone6,2" : .iPhone5S,
            "iPhone7,1" : .iPhone6Plus,
            "iPhone7,2" : .iPhone6,
            "iPhone8,1" : .iPhone6S,
            "iPhone8,2" : .iPhone6SPlus,
            "iPhone8,4" : .iPhoneSE,
            "iPhone9,1" : .iPhone7,
            "iPhone9,3" : .iPhone7,
            "iPhone9,2" : .iPhone7Plus,
            "iPhone9,4" : .iPhone7Plus,
            "iPhone10,1" : .iPhone8,
            "iPhone10,4" : .iPhone8,
            "iPhone10,2" : .iPhone8Plus,
            "iPhone10,5" : .iPhone8Plus,
            "iPhone10,3" : .iPhoneX,
            "iPhone10,6" : .iPhoneX,
            "iPhone11,2" : .iPhoneXS,
            "iPhone11,4" : .iPhoneXSMax,
            "iPhone11,6" : .iPhoneXSMax,
            "iPhone11,8" : .iPhoneXR,
            "iPhone12,1" : .iPhone11,
            "iPhone12,3" : .iPhone11Pro,
            "iPhone12,5" : .iPhone11ProMax,
            "iPhone12,8" : .iPhoneSE2,
            "iPhone13,1" : .iPhone12Mini,
            "iPhone13,2" : .iPhone12,
            "iPhone13,3" : .iPhone12Pro,
            "iPhone13,4" : .iPhone12ProMax,
            "iPhone14,4" : .iPhone13Mini,
            "iPhone14,5" : .iPhone13,
            "iPhone14,2" : .iPhone13Pro,
            "iPhone14,3" : .iPhone13ProMax,
            "iPhone14,6" : .iPhoneSE3,
            "iPhone14,7" : .iPhone14,
            "iPhone14,8" : .iPhone14Plus,
            "iPhone15,2" : .iPhone14Pro,
            "iPhone15,3" : .iPhone14ProMax,
            "iPhone15,4" : .iPhone15,
            "iPhone15,5" : .iPhone15Plus,
            "iPhone16,1" : .iPhone15Pro,
            "iPhone16,2" : .iPhone15ProMax,
            
            // Apple Watch
            "Watch1,1" : .AppleWatch1,
            "Watch1,2" : .AppleWatch1,
            "Watch2,6" : .AppleWatchS1,
            "Watch2,7" : .AppleWatchS1,
            "Watch2,3" : .AppleWatchS2,
            "Watch2,4" : .AppleWatchS2,
            "Watch3,1" : .AppleWatchS3,
            "Watch3,2" : .AppleWatchS3,
            "Watch3,3" : .AppleWatchS3,
            "Watch3,4" : .AppleWatchS3,
            "Watch4,1" : .AppleWatchS4,
            "Watch4,2" : .AppleWatchS4,
            "Watch4,3" : .AppleWatchS4,
            "Watch4,4" : .AppleWatchS4,
            "Watch5,1" : .AppleWatchS5,
            "Watch5,2" : .AppleWatchS5,
            "Watch5,3" : .AppleWatchS5,
            "Watch5,4" : .AppleWatchS5,
            "Watch5,9" : .AppleWatchSE,
            "Watch5,10" : .AppleWatchSE,
            "Watch5,11" : .AppleWatchSE,
            "Watch5,12" : .AppleWatchSE,
            "Watch6,1" : .AppleWatchS6,
            "Watch6,2" : .AppleWatchS6,
            "Watch6,3" : .AppleWatchS6,
            "Watch6,4" : .AppleWatchS6,
            "Watch6,6" : .AppleWatchS7,
            "Watch6,7" : .AppleWatchS7,
            "Watch6,8" : .AppleWatchS7,
            "Watch6,9" : .AppleWatchS7,
    
            //Apple TV
            "AppleTV1,1" : .AppleTV1,
            "AppleTV2,1" : .AppleTV2,
            "AppleTV3,1" : .AppleTV3,
            "AppleTV3,2" : .AppleTV3,
            "AppleTV5,3" : .AppleTV4,
            "AppleTV6,2" : .AppleTV_4K,
            "AppleTV11,1" : .AppleTV2_4K,
            "AppleTV14,1" : .AppleTV3_4K
        ]
    
        guard let mcode = modelCode, let map = String(validatingUTF8: mcode), let model = modelMap[map] else { return Model.unrecognized }
        if model == .simulator {
            if let simModelCode = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
                if let simMap = String(validatingUTF8: simModelCode), let simModel = modelMap[simMap] {
                    return simModel
                }
            }
        }
        return model
    }
}
```

**Usage**:
You can simply get the device model with:

```
let deviceType = UIDevice().type
```

or print the exact string with:

```
print("Running on: \(UIDevice().type)")
Output -> "iPhone X"
```

****Another example with cases****:

```
var myDefaultHeight: CGFloat = 30.0
switch UIDevice().type {
    case .iPhoneSE, .iPhone5, .iPhone5S: print("default value")
    case .iPhone6, .iPhone7, .iPhone8, .iPhone6S, .iPhoneX: myDefaultHeight+= 5
    case .iPhone11, .iPhone12, .iPhone13: myDefaultHeight+= 10
    default: break
}
```

For Apple devices models visit:
https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models

**P.S.:** I've made a little new asyncronous experiment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69225035/1894067) (direct connection with THEIPHONEWIKI site, without long static device list in source code.

Comment: your output is wrong, you have to ask for the `UIDevice().type.rawvalue` to get the device name with spaces.

Comment: I'm not getting the formatted version with spaces using `UIDevice().type`, and if I add `.rawvalue` to the end of that, I get an error stating: Value of type 'Model' has no member 'rawvalue'

Comment: @DJFriar About the `rawvalue` , this one is not longer necessary with **Swift 5**, I've update that line. I've tested now the code and it works correctly, what kind of device are you try to test? Have you other `UIDevice` extensions in your prj?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I'm testing on an iPhone 6s and an iPhone XS Max. Both printing to console and using as a variable return it without spaces. All software is latest public release. No other `UIDevice` extensions aside from yours (housed in a dedicated swift file).

Comment: in order to get the model name with spaces correctly, one must call UIDevice().type.rawValue. Or else you need to change type:Model to type:String and change return values to 'simModel.rawValue', 'model.rawValue', 'Model.unrecognized.rawValue'

Comment: Please add iPhone SE 2nd Gerenation. `iPhone12,8`

Comment: May seem obvious but you need to "import UIKit" 

I also had to do "UIDevice().type.rawValue" to format as "iPhone 11 Pro".

Comment: This solution is not sustainable: you would have to create a new release of your app each time there is a new model.

Comment: @FrédéricAdda An update of your app one time in a year should be normal. The other real solution don't give you output like this kind of code.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I think it would be more than once a year, basically each time Apple releases a new product. I found a more reliable solution based on utsname.

Comment: @FrédéricAdda If you pay attention to my code, I use utsname: my code is an extension of the normal utsname info. IMHO you shouldn't base your app to utsname infos, these are verbose debug informations.

Comment: Does not work for me on iOS 12.4 simulator but does work for iOS 13.5 device

Comment: @VladimirKuzomenskyi Tested now with iOS 12.4 and iPhone SE 1gen simulator: it works. Could you specify the simulator model used?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Yes, I did tested again, the extension does actually work for the simulator! I've just forgot to reinstall my app completely so I didn't see my code working. Sorry for that, your code works! =)

Comment: The "type" is not available anymore. Use UIDevice().name instead

Comment: @Lorenzo According with the latest **Xcode 12.2** with **swift 5.3.1**, **there is no conflicts** with `UIDevice().type`, remember that my extension creates the variable `type` to obtain all the correct informations.

Comment: super accurate, thanx to **Alessandro Ornano** and everybody who participated in! also got a link for this )

Comment: It does not work in Apple Silicon (M1 Mac Mini). It always returns Model.unrecognized in simulators. Although in real devices works as expected (tested in iPhone X and 12 mini).
EDIT: Fixed adding "arm64"    : .simulator, to the dictionary

Comment: This only works sometimes for me (M1 MacBook Pro). It appears to work on simulators with iOS 13.7 and below, but not on any with iOS 14+.

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov Pay attention: there are seven gen of iPods: "iPod1,1"   : .iPod1,
        "iPod2,1"   : .iPod2,
        "iPod3,1"   : .iPod3,
        "iPod4,1"   : .iPod4,
        "iPod5,1"   : .iPod5,
        "iPod7,1"   : .iPod6,
        "iPod9,1"   : .iPod7, where is the mistake? You can check also here https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models

Comment: If any of you have the time and desire, try the experiment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69225035/1894067) just to find out if there are any errors thank you

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Xcode 14 shows `'init(validatingUTF8:)' is deprecated: Use a copy of the String argument`, I'm not sure what to replace it with. Could you help?

Comment: @Arjan Xcode 14 is not released yet (now is RC1) so it's better to await the official release.

Comment: @Arjan If you're looking for a [concise solution to avoid the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77355243/12035498), you can simply use: `guard let mcode = modelCode, let model = modelMap[mcode] else { return Model.unrecognized }`, for the line starting with: `if let model =`. This directly uses `mcode` as the key for modelMap, bypassing the need for the deprecated method.

Answer (score 162):

This **Swift 3.0** example returns the current device model as an `enum` constant (to avoid direct comparisons to string literals). The enum's *raw* value is a `String` containing the human-readable iOS device name. Since it is Swift, the list of recognized devices only includes models recent enough to support iOS releases that include Swift. The following usage example utilizes the implementation at the end of this answer:

```
    switch UIDevice().type {
    case .iPhone5:
              print("No TouchID sensor")
    case .iPhone5S:
              fallthrough
    case .iPhone6:
              fallthrough
    case .iPhone6plus:
              fallthrough
    case .iPad_Pro9_7:
              fallthrough
    case .iPad_Pro12_9:
              fallthrough
    case .iPhone7:
              fallthrough
    case .iPhone7plus:
              print("Put your thumb on the " + 
                     UIDevice().type.rawValue + " TouchID sensor")
    case .unrecognized:
              print("Device model unrecognized");
    default:
              print(UIDevice().type.rawValue + " not supported by this app");
    }
```

Your app should be kept up-to-date for new device releases and also when Apple adds new models for the same device family.  For example, *iPhone3,1 iPhone3,2 iPhone3,4* are all "iPhone 4". Avoid writing code that doesn't account for new models, so your algorithms don't unexpectedly fail to configure or respond to a new device.  You can refer to this maintained list of **[iOS Device Model #'s](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/)**  to update your app at strategic times.

iOS includes device-independent interfaces to detect hardware capabilities and parameters such as screen size. The generalized interfaces Apple provides are usually the safest, best supported mechanisms to dynamically adapt an app's behavior to different hardware. Nevertheless, the following code can be useful for prototyping, debugging, testing, or any time code needs to target a specific device family. This technique can also be useful to describe the current device  by its common/publicly recognized name.

**Swift 3**

```
// 1. Declare outside class definition (or in its own file).
// 2. UIKit must be included in file where this code is added.
// 3. Extends UIDevice class, thus is available anywhere in app.
//
// Usage example:
//
//    if UIDevice().type == .simulator {
//       print("You're running on the simulator... boring!")
//    } else {
//       print("Wow! Running on a \(UIDevice().type.rawValue)")
//    }
import UIKit

public enum Model : String {
    case simulator   = "simulator/sandbox",
    iPod1            = "iPod 1",
    iPod2            = "iPod 2",
    iPod3            = "iPod 3",
    iPod4            = "iPod 4",
    iPod5            = "iPod 5",
    iPad2            = "iPad 2",
    iPad3            = "iPad 3",
    iPad4            = "iPad 4",
    iPhone4          = "iPhone 4",
    iPhone4S         = "iPhone 4S",
    iPhone5          = "iPhone 5",
    iPhone5S         = "iPhone 5S",
    iPhone5C         = "iPhone 5C",
    iPadMini1        = "iPad Mini 1",
    iPadMini2        = "iPad Mini 2",
    iPadMini3        = "iPad Mini 3",
    iPadAir1         = "iPad Air 1",
    iPadAir2         = "iPad Air 2",
    iPadPro9_7       = "iPad Pro 9.7\"",
    iPadPro9_7_cell  = "iPad Pro 9.7\" cellular",
    iPadPro10_5      = "iPad Pro 10.5\"",
    iPadPro10_5_cell = "iPad Pro 10.5\" cellular",
    iPadPro12_9      = "iPad Pro 12.9\"",
    iPadPro12_9_cell = "iPad Pro 12.9\" cellular",
    iPhone6          = "iPhone 6",
    iPhone6plus      = "iPhone 6 Plus",
    iPhone6S         = "iPhone 6S",
    iPhone6Splus     = "iPhone 6S Plus",
    iPhoneSE         = "iPhone SE",
    iPhone7          = "iPhone 7",
    iPhone7plus      = "iPhone 7 Plus",
    iPhone8          = "iPhone 8",
    iPhone8plus      = "iPhone 8 Plus",
    iPhoneX          = "iPhone X",
    iPhoneXS         = "iPhone XS",
    iPhoneXSmax      = "iPhone XS Max",
    iPhoneXR         = "iPhone XR",
    iPhone11         = "iPhone 11",
    iPhone11Pro      = "iPhone 11 Pro",
    iPhone11ProMax   = "iPhone 11 Pro Max",
    unrecognized     = "?unrecognized?"
}

public extension UIDevice {
    public var type: Model {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let modelCode = withUnsafePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
                ptr in String.init(validatingUTF8: ptr)

            }
        }
        var modelMap : [ String : Model ] = [
            "i386"       : .simulator,
            "x86_64"     : .simulator,
            "iPod1,1"    : .iPod1,
            "iPod2,1"    : .iPod2,
            "iPod3,1"    : .iPod3,
            "iPod4,1"    : .iPod4,
            "iPod5,1"    : .iPod5,
            "iPad2,1"    : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,2"    : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,3"    : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,4"    : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,5"    : .iPadMini1,
            "iPad2,6"    : .iPadMini1,
            "iPad2,7"    : .iPadMini1,
            "iPhone3,1"  : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone3,2"  : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone3,3"  : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone4,1"  : .iPhone4S,
            "iPhone5,1"  : .iPhone5,
            "iPhone5,2"  : .iPhone5,
            "iPhone5,3"  : .iPhone5C,
            "iPhone5,4"  : .iPhone5C,
            "iPad3,1"    : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,2"    : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,3"    : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,4"    : .iPad4,
            "iPad3,5"    : .iPad4,
            "iPad3,6"    : .iPad4,
            "iPhone6,1"  : .iPhone5S,
            "iPhone6,2"  : .iPhone5S,
            "iPad4,1"    : .iPadAir1,
            "iPad4,2"    : .iPadAir2,
            "iPad4,4"    : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,5"    : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,6"    : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,7"    : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad4,8"    : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad4,9"    : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad6,3"    : .iPadPro9_7,
            "iPad6,11"   : .iPadPro9_7,
            "iPad6,4"    : .iPadPro9_7_cell,
            "iPad6,12"   : .iPadPro9_7_cell,
            "iPad6,7"    : .iPadPro12_9,
            "iPad6,8"    : .iPadPro12_9_cell,
            "iPad7,3"    : .iPadPro10_5,
            "iPad7,4"    : .iPadPro10_5_cell,
            "iPhone7,1"  : .iPhone6plus,
            "iPhone7,2"  : .iPhone6,
            "iPhone8,1"  : .iPhone6S,
            "iPhone8,2"  : .iPhone6Splus,
            "iPhone8,4"  : .iPhoneSE,
            "iPhone9,1"  : .iPhone7,
            "iPhone9,2"  : .iPhone7plus,
            "iPhone9,3"  : .iPhone7,
            "iPhone9,4"  : .iPhone7plus,
            "iPhone10,1" : .iPhone8,
            "iPhone10,2" : .iPhone8plus,
            "iPhone10,3" : .iPhoneX,
            "iPhone10,6" : .iPhoneX,
            "iPhone11,2" : .iPhoneXS,
            "iPhone11,4" : .iPhoneXSmax,
            "iPhone11,6" : .iPhoneXSmax,
            "iPhone11,8" : .iPhoneXR,
            "iPhone12,1" : .iPhone11,
            "iPhone12,3" : .iPhone11Pro,
            "iPhone12,5" : .iPhone11ProMax
        ]

    if let model = modelMap[String.init(validatingUTF8: modelCode!)!] {
            return model
        }
        return Model.unrecognized
    }
}
```

Comment: On Swift 2 replace:                                                                                         let machinePtr = advance(ptr.baseAddress, Int(_SYS_NAMELEN * 4)) with  let machinePtr = ptr.baseAddress.advancedBy(Int(_SYS_NAMELEN * 4))

Comment: you do have duplicate keys in `modelMap` that makes iOS to complain: `Duplicate literals in keys`

Comment: The latest Swift 3.0.2 complains about the part `if let model = modelMap[String.fromCString(modelCode!)!]`. Workaround can be decoding CString first and then feeding decoded string to `modelMap`

`
if let (str, _) = String.decodeCString(modelCode, as: UTF8.self, repairingInvalidCodeUnits: false) {
            if let model = modelMap[str] {
                return model
            }
        }
`

Comment: As @alekperos says there is a typo in the code. It should be : `if let model = modelMap[String.init(validatingUTF8: deviceModelCode()!)!] {
            return model
        }`

Comment: Dose someone know What string will be returned as modelCode! if user using iPhoneSE ?

Comment: Thanks, updating for recent device is always helpful.

Comment: @clearlight which dimension category represents the iPad Pro?

Comment: @clearlight I am using your updated code and testing on `iPad Pro (9.7 inch) - iOS 10.2 (14C89)` Simulator but it is categorized as unrecognized. What could be the reason? I thought it should be recognized as simulator.

Comment: Where is the configuration for iPhone Xs, Max and Xr?

Answer (score 144):

Yet another/simple alternative (model identifier reference found at https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models):

**Updated answer for Swift 3/4/5 including string trimming and simulator support:**

```
func modelIdentifier() -> String {
    if let simulatorModelIdentifier = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] { return simulatorModelIdentifier }
    var sysinfo = utsname()
    uname(&sysinfo) // ignore return value
    return String(bytes: Data(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, count: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN)), encoding: .ascii)!.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)
}
```

Comment: is this public api or private? I mean can I use it in my application that I want to put in App Store?

Comment: Hi @JafarKhoshtabiat :) It is part of UNIX and I have used it in apps on App Store for many years :)

Comment: For simulator detection use:
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
#endif

Comment: That's the best answer if you need it to work across macos and ios.

Comment: Btw the iPhone 11 simulator returns `Phone12,1`, what gives? And the simulator detection isn't working at all.

Comment: @Houman not sure what you mean? The code returns "12,1" for both iPhone 11 simulator and real iPhone 11, which is the whole idea! If you leave out the line with `if let...` then you will not get "12,1" when running in simulator :)

Comment: @Houman Identifer is different than the device model. So it is expected to get "12,1" as the output. Check the link in the answer.

Comment: > `ignore return value` - The return value for that function is an error code. Best to not ignore errors.

Comment: @KyLeggiero please check the documentation for `uname`. As you can see it will only fail if you don’t provide a proper structure. But I do that and so it is irrelevant. This is the reason for my comment so the reader can see that I have taken an active decision not to check the return value. But feel free to add this in your own version if you are worried 

Comment: @JensSchwarzer My system's documentation for `uname` and the official UNIX specification both say that `uname` returns a non-zero integer when an error occurred, without specifying a scope for the error: https://i.imgur.com/SODOhiJ.png - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uname.html

Comment: @KyLeggiero Yikes! Well, I am pretty sure it never failed. But feel free to add a test in your own code if this keeps you awake at night ;)

Comment: @Aura this is correct. Please check the webpage in the beginning for look-up for a specific version :)

Answer (score 40):

I've made another sample extension on UIDevice to include simulator model identifier base on @HAS's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/3367915) . It's working fine with Swift3.2 above(include Swift 4.x, Swift 5):

```
let modelName = UIDevice.current.modelName
```

**New add Models: iPod touch (7th generation), iPhone SE (2nd generation), iPhone 12 mini, iPhone 12, iPhone 12 Pro, iPhone 12 Pro Max, iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)**

```
import UIKit

public extension UIDevice {

    /// pares the deveice name as the standard name
    var modelName: String {

        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
            let identifier = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"]!
        #else
            var systemInfo = utsname()
            uname(&systemInfo)
            let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
            let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
                guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return identifier }
                return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
            }
        #endif

        switch identifier {
        case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
        case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
        case "iPod9,1":                                 return "iPod touch (7th generation)"
        case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
        case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
        case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
        case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
        case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
        case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
        case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
        case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
        case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
        case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3":                  return "iPhone 7"
        case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4":                  return "iPhone 7 Plus"
        case "iPhone8,4":                               return "iPhone SE"
        case "iPhone10,1", "iPhone10,4":                return "iPhone 8"
        case "iPhone10,2", "iPhone10,5":                return "iPhone 8 Plus"
        case "iPhone10,3", "iPhone10,6":                return "iPhone X"
        case "iPhone11,2":                              return "iPhone XS"
        case "iPhone11,4", "iPhone11,6":                return "iPhone XS Max"
        case "iPhone11,8":                              return "iPhone XR"
        case "iPhone12,1":                              return "iPhone 11"
        case "iPhone12,3":                              return "iPhone 11 Pro"
        case "iPhone12,5":                              return "iPhone 11 Pro Max"
        case "iPhone12,8":                              return "iPhone SE (2nd generation)"
        case "iPhone13,1":                              return "iPhone 12 mini"
        case "iPhone13,2":                              return "iPhone 12"
        case "iPhone13,3":                              return "iPhone 12 Pro"
        case "iPhone13,4":                              return "iPhone 12 Pro Max"
        case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
        case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
        case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
        case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
        case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
        case "iPad6,11", "iPad6,12":                    return "iPad 5"
        case "iPad7,5", "iPad7,6":                      return "iPad 6"
        case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
        case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
        case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
        case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
        case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4":                      return "iPad Pro 9.7 Inch"
        case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":                      return "iPad Pro 12.9 Inch"
        case "iPad7,1", "iPad7,2":                      return "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)"
        case "iPad7,3", "iPad7,4":                      return "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)"
        case "iPad8,1", "iPad8,2", "iPad8,3", "iPad8,4":return "iPad Pro (11-inch)"
        case "iPad8,5", "iPad8,6", "iPad8,7", "iPad8,8":return "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)"
        case "iPad8,11", "iPad8,12":                    return "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)"
        case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
        case "AppleTV6,2":                              return "Apple TV 4K"
        case "AudioAccessory1,1":                       return "HomePod"
        default:                                        return identifier
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

## Swift 5

```
/// Obtain the machine hardware platform from the `uname()` unix command
///
/// Example of return values
///  - `"iPhone8,1"` = iPhone 6s
///  - `"iPad6,7"` = iPad Pro (12.9-inch)
static var unameMachine: String {
    var utsnameInstance = utsname()
    uname(&utsnameInstance)
    let optionalString: String? = withUnsafePointer(to: &utsnameInstance.machine) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
            ptr in String.init(validatingUTF8: ptr)
        }
    }
    return optionalString ?? "N/A"
}
```

Comment: this one has the added bonus of being non-UIKit dependent

Comment: A shame, this solution looks great. But I can't get it to work on Swift 5. Any advice?

Comment: People missing the point: Apple doesn't give you "iPhone 12 Max", it gives you these command separated strings, you need to then map them to their "plain text" model names! He even cals this out in the code block header!!!

Answer (score 18):

Using Swift 3 (Xcode 8.3)

```
    func deviceName() -> String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let str = withUnsafePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine.0) { ptr in
            return String(cString: ptr)
        }
        return str
    }
```

Note: According to official dev forum answer, it is safe to use tuples in this way. Memory alignment for the big Int8 tuple will be the same as if it were a big Int8 array. ie: contiguous and not-padded.

Comment: this one has the added bonus of being non-UIKit dependent

Comment: This answer is underrated! So much simpler than using a Mirror. You can even simplify this further by omitting the `withUnsafePointer` call like this: `return String(cString: &sysinfo.machine.0)`

Comment: @mklbtz Good tip, only issue with that is that it returns an optional String. I expect the return value of something like `deviceName()` to be a non-optional or I'd be using your suggestion.

Comment: @Stunner mm, maybe you misunderstood me but no this doesn't make it optional.
```
func deviceName() -> String {
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    return String(cString: &systemInfo.machine.0)
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it in Xcode 14/Swift 5.7. Also `return String(cString: &sysinfo.machine.0)` will crash on 5.7 due to a recent change in the String(cString:) implementation.

Answer (score 16):

For both device as well as simulators,
Create a new swift file with name UIDevice.swift

Add the below code

```
import UIKit


public extension UIDevice {

var modelName: String {
    #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
        let DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR = true
    #else
        let DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR = false
    #endif

    var machineString : String = ""

    if DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR == true
    {

        if let dir = NSProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
            machineString = dir
        }
    }
    else {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        machineString = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }
    }
    switch machineString {
    case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
    case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
    case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
    case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
    case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
    case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
    case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
    case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
    case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
    case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
    case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
    case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
    case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
    case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
    case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
    case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
    case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
    case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
    case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
    case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
    case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":                      return "iPad Pro"
    case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
    default:                                        return machineString
    }
}
}
```

Then in your viewcontroller,

```
 let deviceType = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName

    if deviceType.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("iphone 4") != nil {
       print("iPhone 4 or iphone 4s")
    }
    else if deviceType.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("iphone 5") != nil {
        print("iPhone 5 or iphone 5s or iphone 5c")
    }
   else if deviceType.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("iphone 6") != nil {
        print("iPhone 6 Series")
    }
```

Comment: XCode 7.2 says that line if let dir = NSProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] will never be executed.

Comment: @DeepakThakur, did u try running in simulator? me too using Xcode 7.2, it's working fine

Comment: iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus size are different. How to handle this?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey, in that method it'll return "iPhone 6 Plus" for 6 plus, u can check...

Comment: And the Objective-C equivalent to get the simulator type is:  [NSProcessInfo processInfo].environment[@"SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"]

Answer (score 16):

Here's the solution updated for January 2023. It includes the most recent iPhone, iPad, Watch, iPod, Apple TV, and HomePod:

```
extension UIDevice {
    
    static var modelName: String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }

        switch identifier {
            // MARK: - iPhone
            case "i386", "x86_64", "arm64": return "iPhone Simulator"
            case "iPhone1,1": return "iPhone"
            case "iPhone1,2": return "iPhone 3G"
            case "iPhone2,1": return "iPhone 3GS"
            case "iPhone3,1": return "iPhone 4"
            case "iPhone3,2": return "iPhone 4 GSM Rev A"
            case "iPhone3,3": return "iPhone 4 CDMA"
            case "iPhone4,1": return "iPhone 4S"
            case "iPhone5,1": return "iPhone 5 (GSM)"
            case "iPhone5,2": return "iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)"
            case "iPhone5,3": return "iPhone 5C (GSM)"
            case "iPhone5,4": return "iPhone 5C (Global)"
            case "iPhone6,1": return "iPhone 5S (GSM)"
            case "iPhone6,2": return "iPhone 5S (Global)"
            case "iPhone7,1": return "iPhone 6 Plus"
            case "iPhone7,2": return "iPhone 6"
            case "iPhone8,1": return "iPhone 6s"
            case "iPhone8,2": return "iPhone 6s Plus"
            case "iPhone8,4": return "iPhone SE (GSM)"
            case "iPhone9,1": return "iPhone 7"
            case "iPhone9,2": return "iPhone 7 Plus"
            case "iPhone9,3": return "iPhone 7"
            case "iPhone9,4": return "iPhone 7 Plus"
            case "iPhone10,1": return "iPhone 8"
            case "iPhone10,2": return "iPhone 8 Plus"
            case "iPhone10,3": return "iPhone X Global"
            case "iPhone10,4": return "iPhone 8"
            case "iPhone10,5": return "iPhone 8 Plus"
            case "iPhone10,6": return "iPhone X GSM"
            case "iPhone11,2": return "iPhone XS"
            case "iPhone11,4": return "iPhone XS Max"
            case "iPhone11,6": return "iPhone XS Max Global"
            case "iPhone11,8": return "iPhone XR"
            case "iPhone12,1": return "iPhone 11"
            case "iPhone12,3": return "iPhone 11 Pro"
            case "iPhone12,5": return "iPhone 11 Pro Max"
            case "iPhone12,8": return "iPhone SE 2nd Gen"
            case "iPhone13,1": return "iPhone 12 Mini"
            case "iPhone13,2": return "iPhone 12"
            case "iPhone13,3": return "iPhone 12 Pro"
            case "iPhone13,4": return "iPhone 12 Pro Max"
            case "iPhone14,2": return "iPhone 13 Pro"
            case "iPhone14,3": return "iPhone 13 Pro Max"
            case "iPhone14,4": return "iPhone 13 Mini"
            case "iPhone14,5": return "iPhone 13"
            case "iPhone14,6": return "iPhone SE 3rd Gen"
            case "iPhone14,7": return "iPhone 14"
            case "iPhone14,8": return "iPhone 14 Plus"
            case "iPhone15,2": return "iPhone 14 Pro"
            case "iPhone15,3": return "iPhone 14 Pro Max"
            case "iPhone15,4": return "iPhone 15"
            case "iPhone15,5": return "iPhone 15 Plus"
            case "iPhone16,1": return "iPhone 15 Pro"
            case "iPhone16,2": return "iPhone 15 Pro Max"
            
            // MARK: - iPod
            case "iPod1,1": return "1st Gen iPod"
            case "iPod2,1": return "2nd Gen iPod"
            case "iPod3,1": return "3rd Gen iPod"
            case "iPod4,1": return "4th Gen iPod"
            case "iPod5,1": return "5th Gen iPod"
            case "iPod7,1": return "6th Gen iPod"
            case "iPod9,1": return "7th Gen iPod"
            
            // MARK: - iPad
            case "iPad1,1": return "iPad"
            case "iPad1,2": return "iPad 3G"
            case "iPad2,1": return "2nd Gen iPad"
            case "iPad2,2": return "2nd Gen iPad GSM"
            case "iPad2,3": return "2nd Gen iPad CDMA"
            case "iPad2,4": return "2nd Gen iPad New Revision"
            case "iPad3,1": return "3rd Gen iPad"
            case "iPad3,2": return "3rd Gen iPad CDMA"
            case "iPad3,3": return "3rd Gen iPad GSM"
            case "iPad2,5": return "iPad mini"
            case "iPad2,6": return "iPad mini GSM+LTE"
            case "iPad2,7": return "iPad mini CDMA+LTE"
            case "iPad3,4": return "4th Gen iPad"
            case "iPad3,5": return "4th Gen iPad GSM+LTE"
            case "iPad3,6": return "4th Gen iPad CDMA+LTE"
            case "iPad4,1": return "iPad Air (WiFi)"
            case "iPad4,2": return "iPad Air (GSM+CDMA)"
            case "iPad4,3": return "1st Gen iPad Air (China)"
            case "iPad4,4": return "iPad mini Retina (WiFi)"
            case "iPad4,5": return "iPad mini Retina (GSM+CDMA)"
            case "iPad4,6": return "iPad mini Retina (China)"
            case "iPad4,7": return "iPad mini 3 (WiFi)"
            case "iPad4,8": return "iPad mini 3 (GSM+CDMA)"
            case "iPad4,9": return "iPad Mini 3 (China)"
            case "iPad5,1": return "iPad mini 4 (WiFi)"
            case "iPad5,2": return "4th Gen iPad mini (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad5,3": return "iPad Air 2 (WiFi)"
            case "iPad5,4": return "iPad Air 2 (Cellular)"
            case "iPad6,3": return "iPad Pro (9.7 inch, WiFi)"
            case "iPad6,4": return "iPad Pro (9.7 inch, WiFi+LTE)"
            case "iPad6,7": return "iPad Pro (12.9 inch, WiFi)"
            case "iPad6,8": return "iPad Pro (12.9 inch, WiFi+LTE)"
            case "iPad6,11": return "iPad (2017)"
            case "iPad6,12": return "iPad (2017)"
            case "iPad7,1": return "iPad Pro 2nd Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad7,2": return "iPad Pro 2nd Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad7,3": return "iPad Pro 10.5-inch 2nd Gen"
            case "iPad7,4": return "iPad Pro 10.5-inch 2nd Gen"
            case "iPad7,5": return "iPad 6th Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad7,6": return "iPad 6th Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad7,11": return "iPad 7th Gen 10.2-inch (WiFi)"
            case "iPad7,12": return "iPad 7th Gen 10.2-inch (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad8,1": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 3rd Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad8,2": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 3rd Gen (1TB, WiFi)"
            case "iPad8,3": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 3rd Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad8,4": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 3rd Gen (1TB, WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad8,5": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 3rd Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad8,6": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 3rd Gen (1TB, WiFi)"
            case "iPad8,7": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 3rd Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad8,8": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 3rd Gen (1TB, WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad8,9": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 4th Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad8,10": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 4th Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad8,11": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 4th Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad8,12": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 4th Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad11,1": return "iPad mini 5th Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad11,2": return "iPad mini 5th Gen"
            case "iPad11,3": return "iPad Air 3rd Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad11,4": return "iPad Air 3rd Gen"
            case "iPad11,6": return "iPad 8th Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad11,7": return "iPad 8th Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad12,1": return "iPad 9th Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad12,2": return "iPad 9th Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad14,1": return "iPad mini 6th Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad14,2": return "iPad mini 6th Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad13,1": return "iPad Air 4th Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad13,2": return "iPad Air 4th Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad13,4": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 5th Gen"
            case "iPad13,5": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 5th Gen"
            case "iPad13,6": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 5th Gen"
            case "iPad13,7": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 5th Gen"
            case "iPad13,8": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 5th Gen"
            case "iPad13,9": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 5th Gen"
            case "iPad13,10": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 5th Gen"
            case "iPad13,11": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 5th Gen"
            case "iPad13,16": return "iPad Air 5th Gen (WiFi)"
            case "iPad13,17": return "iPad Air 5th Gen (WiFi+Cellular)"
            case "iPad13,18": return "iPad 10th Gen"
            case "iPad13,19": return "iPad 10th Gen"
            case "iPad14,3": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 4th Gen"
            case "iPad14,4": return "iPad Pro 11 inch 4th Gen"
            case "iPad14,5": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 6th Gen"
            case "iPad14,6": return "iPad Pro 12.9 inch 6th Gen"
            
            // MARK: - Watch
            case "Watch1,1": return "Apple Watch 38mm case"
            case "Watch1,2": return "Apple Watch 42mm case"
            case "Watch2,6": return "Apple Watch Series 1 38mm case"
            case "Watch2,7": return "Apple Watch Series 1 42mm case"
            case "Watch2,3": return "Apple Watch Series 2 38mm case"
            case "Watch2,4": return "Apple Watch Series 2 42mm case"
            case "Watch3,1": return "Apple Watch Series 3 38mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch3,2": return "Apple Watch Series 3 42mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch3,3": return "Apple Watch Series 3 38mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch3,4": return "Apple Watch Series 3 42mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch4,1": return "Apple Watch Series 4 40mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch4,2": return "Apple Watch Series 4 44mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch4,3": return "Apple Watch Series 4 40mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch4,4": return "Apple Watch Series 4 44mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch5,1": return "Apple Watch Series 5 40mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch5,2": return "Apple Watch Series 5 44mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch5,3": return "Apple Watch Series 5 40mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch5,4": return "Apple Watch Series 5 44mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch5,9": return "Apple Watch SE 40mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch5,10": return "Apple Watch SE 44mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch5,11": return "Apple Watch SE 40mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch5,12": return "Apple Watch SE 44mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch6,1": return "Apple Watch Series 6 40mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch6,2": return "Apple Watch Series 6 44mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch6,3": return "Apple Watch Series 6 40mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch6,4": return "Apple Watch Series 6 44mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch6,6": return "Apple Watch Series 7 41mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch6,7": return "Apple Watch Series 7 45mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch6,8": return "Apple Watch Series 7 41mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch6,9": return "Apple Watch Series 7 45mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch6,10": return "Apple Watch SE 40mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch6,11": return "Apple Watch SE 44mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch6,12": return "Apple Watch SE 40mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch6,13": return "Apple Watch SE 44mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch6,14": return "Apple Watch Series 8 41mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch6,15": return "Apple Watch Series 8 45mm case (GPS)"
            case "Watch6,16": return "Apple Watch Series 8 41mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch6,17": return "Apple Watch Series 8 45mm case (GPS+Cellular)"
            case "Watch6,18": return "Apple Watch Ultra"
            
            // MARK: - Apple TV
            case "AppleTV5,3": return "Apple TV"
            case "AppleTV6,2": return "Apple TV 4K"
            
            // MARK: - HomePod
            case "AudioAccessory1,1": return "HomePod"
            case "AudioAccessory5,1": return "HomePod mini"
            
            // MARK: - Unrecognized
            default: return identifier
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
UIDevice.modelName
```

Answer (score 13):

Dealing with c structs is painful in swift. Especially if they have some kind of c arrays in it. Here is my solution: Continue to use objective-c. Just create a wrapper objective-c class that does this job and then use that class in swift. Here is a sample class that does exactly this:

```
@interface DeviceInfo : NSObject

+ (NSString *)model;

@end

#import "DeviceInfo.h"
#import <sys/utsname.h>

@implementation DeviceInfo

+ (NSString *)model
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString: systemInfo.machine encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

@end
```

In swift side:

```
let deviceModel = DeviceInfo.model()
```

Comment: Thanks mstysf. 
But I think I have found a solution in here <http://stackoverflow.com/a/25380129>. 

However, do you you know whether it is possible to tell between iPhone Simulators (iPhone4s,iPhone5,iPhone6)? Because it seems to me that it only returns "x86_64" for all iPhone Simulators no matter what model I have chosen.

Comment: Sorry I think an error occurred while coping. Here is the link :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25380129/2640210

Comment: @TheMachSystem That's the whole problem with this approach. It isn't the right way to adapt your app's behavior in most cases. You should be sniffing out the hardware configuration and characteristics using more generalized standard iOS interfaces wherever possible although that might require some more research and coding effort.

Comment: @TheMachSystem Chiming in a bit late perhaps, but the answer to your question (if it's possible to differentiate between iDevice models in the Simulator) is no. The reason you're getting `x86_64` from `utsname` is that the Simulator is actually your computer which has the `machine` property `x86_64`. Try by changing `.machine` to `.nodename` in your method the return value will be something like `My-iMac.local`.

Answer (score 9):

I found that a lot all these answers use strings. I decided to change @HAS answer to use an enum:

```
public enum Devices: String {
    case IPodTouch5
    case IPodTouch6
    case IPhone4
    case IPhone4S
    case IPhone5
    case IPhone5C
    case IPhone5S
    case IPhone6
    case IPhone6Plus
    case IPhone6S
    case IPhone6SPlus
    case IPhone7
    case IPhone7Plus
    case IPhoneSE
    case IPad2
    case IPad3
    case IPad4
    case IPadAir
    case IPadAir2
    case IPadMini
    case IPadMini2
    case IPadMini3
    case IPadMini4
    case IPadPro
    case AppleTV
    case Simulator
    case Other
}

public extension UIDevice {

    public var modelName: Devices {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8 , value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }

        switch identifier {
        case "iPod5,1":                                 return Devices.IPodTouch5
        case "iPod7,1":                                 return Devices.IPodTouch6
        case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return Devices.IPhone4
        case "iPhone4,1":                               return Devices.IPhone4S
        case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return Devices.IPhone5
        case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return Devices.IPhone5C
        case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return Devices.IPhone5S
        case "iPhone7,2":                               return Devices.IPhone6
        case "iPhone7,1":                               return Devices.IPhone6Plus
        case "iPhone8,1":                               return Devices.IPhone6S
        case "iPhone8,2":                               return Devices.IPhone6SPlus
        case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3":                  return Devices.IPhone7
        case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4":                  return Devices.IPhone7Plus
        case "iPhone8,4":                               return Devices.IPhoneSE
        case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return Devices.IPad2
        case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return Devices.IPad3
        case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return Devices.IPad4
        case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return Devices.IPadAir
        case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return Devices.IPadAir2
        case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return Devices.IPadMini
        case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return Devices.IPadMini2
        case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return Devices.IPadMini3
        case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return Devices.IPadMini4
        case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4", "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":return Devices.IPadPro
        case "AppleTV5,3":                              return Devices.AppleTV
        case "i386", "x86_64":                          return Devices.Simulator
        default:                                        return Devices.Other
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've implemented a **super-lightweight library to detect the used device** based on some of the given answers: https://github.com/schickling/Device.swift

It can be installed via [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) and be used like this:

```
import Device

let deviceType = UIDevice.currentDevice().deviceType

switch deviceType {
case .IPhone6: print("Do stuff for iPhone6")
case .IPadMini: print("Do stuff for iPad mini")
default: print("Check other available cases of DeviceType")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### WikiDevice

**the asynchronous library that gives you the answer from theiphonewiki**

A crazy little experiment for automation fans like me. I made this algorithm that reads the identification code of the device, physical or simulated, and load the [theiphonewiki](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models) page to extrapolate the model name based on the identification code (example *iPhone11,2* -> **iPhone XS**). The algorithm interfaces with the WIKI page using the internal Wiki API Sandbox tool that allows you to have a JSON response, however the content is not obtainable in JSON (just the part that was needed, that is the wikitables) so I parsed the HTML content to get to the device name, without using third parts HTML parsing libraries.

**PROS**: always updated, you don't need to add new devices

**CONS**: asyncronous answer using the wiki page from web

P.S. *Feel free to improve my code to get an even more precise result and a more elegant syntax*
P.S.S. *If you need a more immediate answer use my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234519/1894067) in this page*

```
public extension UIDevice {
    var identifier: String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let modelCode = withUnsafePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
                ptr in String.init(validatingUTF8: ptr)
            }
        }
        if modelCode == "x86_64" {
            if let simModelCode = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
                if let simMap = String(validatingUTF8: simModelCode) {
                    return simMap
                }
            }
        }
        return modelCode ?? "?unrecognized?"
    }
}
class WikiDevice {
    static func model(_ completion: @escaping ((String) -> ())){
        let unrecognized = "?unrecognized?"
        guard let wikiUrl=URL(string:"https://www.theiphonewiki.com//w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Models") else { return completion(unrecognized) }
        var identifier: String {
            var systemInfo = utsname()
            uname(&systemInfo)
            let modelCode = withUnsafePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
                $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
                    ptr in String.init(validatingUTF8: ptr)
                }
            }
            if modelCode == "x86_64" {
                if let simModelCode = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
                    if let simMap = String(validatingUTF8: simModelCode) {
                        return simMap
                    }
                }
            }
            return modelCode ?? unrecognized
        }
        guard identifier != unrecognized else { return completion(unrecognized)}
        let request = URLRequest(url: wikiUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                guard let data = data,
                    let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200 ..< 300) ~= response.statusCode,
                    error == nil else { return completion(unrecognized) }
                guard let convertedString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return completion(unrecognized) }
                var wikiTables = convertedString.components(separatedBy: "wikitable")
                wikiTables.removeFirst()
                var tables = [[String]]()
                wikiTables.enumerated().forEach{ index,table in
                    let rawRows = table.components(separatedBy: #"<tr>\n<td"#)
                    var counter = 0
                    var rows = [String]()
                    while counter < rawRows.count {
                        let rawRow = rawRows[counter]
                        if let subRowsNum = rawRow.components(separatedBy: #"rowspan=\""#).dropFirst().compactMap({ sub in
                            (sub.range(of: #"\">"#)?.lowerBound).flatMap { endRange in
                                String(sub[sub.startIndex ..< endRange])
                            }
                        }).first {
                            if let subRowsTot = Int(subRowsNum) {
                                var otherRows = ""
                                for i in counter..<counter+subRowsTot {
                                    otherRows += rawRows[i]
                                }
                                let row = rawRow + otherRows
                                rows.append(row)
                                counter += subRowsTot-1
                            }
                        } else {
                            rows.append(rawRows[counter])
                        }
                        counter += 1
                    }
                    tables.append(rows)
                }
                for table in tables {
                    if let rowIndex = table.firstIndex(where: {$0.lowercased().contains(identifier.lowercased())}) {
                        let rows = table[rowIndex].components(separatedBy: "<td>")
                        if rows.count>0 {
                            if rows[0].contains("title") { //hyperlink
                                if let (cleanedGen) = rows[0].components(separatedBy: #">"#).dropFirst().compactMap({ sub in
                                    (sub.range(of: "</")?.lowerBound).flatMap { endRange in
                                        String(sub[sub.startIndex ..< endRange]).replacingOccurrences(of: #"\n"#, with: "")
                                    }
                                }).first {
                                    completion(cleanedGen)
                                }
                            } else {
                                let raw = rows[0].replacingOccurrences(of: "<td>", with: "")
                                let cleanedGen = raw.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\n"#, with: "")
                                completion(cleanedGen)
                            }
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
                completion(unrecognized)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
var deviceModel:String = ""
WikiDevice.model { (model) in
     print("Using WikiDevice, running on: \(model)")
     deviceModel = model
}
```

### Output:

```
Using WikiDevice, running on: iPhone 11 Pro Max
```

### GitHUB:

If you need to test this library you can download the test project from [here](https://github.com/aornano/WikiDevice)

Comment: This is an awesome solution! The only obvious limitation is that it requires a network. I wrote an auto updating Swift package that works offline: https://github.com/ptrkstr/Devices

Answer (score 6):

There are some problems with the accepted answer when you're using Swift 3!
This answer (inspired from NAZIK) works with Swift 3 and the new iPhone models:

```
import UIKit


public extension UIDevice {
var modelName: String {
    #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
        let DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR = true
    #else
        let DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR = false
    #endif

    var machineString = String()

    if DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR == true
    {
        if let dir = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
            machineString = dir
        }
    }
    else {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        machineString = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8 , value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }
    }
    switch machineString {
    case "iPod4,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 4G"
    case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5G"
    case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6G"
    case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
    case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
    case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
    case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
    case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
    case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
    case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
    case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
    case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
    case "iPhone8,4":                               return "iPhone SE"
    case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3":                  return "iPhone 7"
    case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone 9,4":                 return "iPhone 7 Plus"
    case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
    case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
    case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
    case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
    case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
    case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
    case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
    case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
    case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
    case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4":                      return "iPad Pro (9.7 inch)"
    case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":                      return "iPad Pro (12.9 inch)"
    case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
    default:                                        return machineString
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.0 or higher**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let device = UIDevice.current

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let model = device.model
        print(model) // e.g. "iPhone"

        let modelName = device.modelName
        print(modelName) // e.g. "iPhone 6"  /* see the extension */

        let deviceName = device.name
        print(deviceName) // e.g. "My iPhone"

        let systemName = device.systemName
        print(systemName) // e.g. "iOS"

        let systemVersion = device.systemVersion
        print(systemVersion) // e.g. "10.3.2"

        if let identifierForVendor = device.identifierForVendor {

            print(identifierForVendor) // e.g. "E1X2XX34-5X6X-7890-123X-XXX456C78901"
        }
    }
}
```

**and add the following extension**

```
extension UIDevice {

    var modelName: String {

        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)

        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)

        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }

        switch identifier {

        case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
        case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
        case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
        case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
        case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
        case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
        case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
        case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
        case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
        case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
        case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
        case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3":                  return "iPhone 7"
        case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4":                  return "iPhone 7 Plus"
        case "iPhone8,4":                               return "iPhone SE"
        case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
        case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
        case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
        case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
        case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
        case "iPad6,11", "iPad6,12":                    return "iPad 5"
        case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
        case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
        case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
        case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
        case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4":                      return "iPad Pro 9.7 Inch"
        case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":                      return "iPad Pro 12.9 Inch"
        case "iPad7,1", "iPad7,2":                      return "iPad Pro 12.9 Inch 2. Generation"
        case "iPad7,3", "iPad7,4":                      return "iPad Pro 10.5 Inch"
        case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
        case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
        default:                                        return identifier
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: let deviceName = device.name
        print(deviceName).  getting Ambiguous use of 'name' error

Answer (score 5):

There is a helper [library](https://github.com/devicekit/DeviceKit) for this.

**Swift 5**

> pod 'DeviceKit', '~> 2.0'

**Swift 4.0 - Swift 4.2**

> pod 'DeviceKit', '~> 1.3'

if you just want to determine the model and make something accordingly.

You can use like that :

```
let isIphoneX = Device().isOneOf([.iPhoneX, .simulator(.iPhoneX)])
```

In a function :

```
func isItIPhoneX() -> Bool {
    let device = Device()
    let check = device.isOneOf([.iPhoneX, .iPhoneXr , .iPhoneXs , .iPhoneXsMax ,
                                .simulator(.iPhoneX), .simulator(.iPhoneXr) , .simulator(.iPhoneXs) , .simulator(.iPhoneXsMax) ])
    return check
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here an modification without force unwrap and Swift 3.0:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


public enum Model : String {
    case simulator = "simulator/sandbox",
    iPod1          = "iPod 1",
    iPod2          = "iPod 2",
    iPod3          = "iPod 3",
    iPod4          = "iPod 4",
    iPod5          = "iPod 5",
    iPad2          = "iPad 2",
    iPad3          = "iPad 3",
    iPad4          = "iPad 4",
    iPhone4        = "iPhone 4",
    iPhone4S       = "iPhone 4S",
    iPhone5        = "iPhone 5",
    iPhone5S       = "iPhone 5S",
    iPhone5C       = "iPhone 5C",
    iPadMini1      = "iPad Mini 1",
    iPadMini2      = "iPad Mini 2",
    iPadMini3      = "iPad Mini 3",
    iPadAir1       = "iPad Air 1",
    iPadAir2       = "iPad Air 2",
    iPhone6        = "iPhone 6",
    iPhone6plus    = "iPhone 6 Plus",
    iPhone6S       = "iPhone 6S",
    iPhone6Splus   = "iPhone 6S Plus",
    iPhoneSE       = "iPhone SE",
    iPhone7        = "iPhone 7",
    iPhone7plus    = "iPhone 7 Plus",
    unrecognized   = "?unrecognized?"
}

public extension UIDevice {
    public var type: Model {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let modelCode = withUnsafePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
                ptr in String.init(validatingUTF8: ptr)

            }
        }
        var modelMap : [ String : Model ] = [
            "i386"      : .simulator,
            "x86_64"    : .simulator,
            "iPod1,1"   : .iPod1,
            "iPod2,1"   : .iPod2,
            "iPod3,1"   : .iPod3,
            "iPod4,1"   : .iPod4,
            "iPod5,1"   : .iPod5,
            "iPad2,1"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,2"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,3"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,4"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,5"   : .iPadMini1,
            "iPad2,6"   : .iPadMini1,
            "iPad2,7"   : .iPadMini1,
            "iPhone3,1" : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone3,2" : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone3,3" : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone4,1" : .iPhone4S,
            "iPhone5,1" : .iPhone5,
            "iPhone5,2" : .iPhone5,
            "iPhone5,3" : .iPhone5C,
            "iPhone5,4" : .iPhone5C,
            "iPad3,1"   : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,2"   : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,3"   : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,4"   : .iPad4,
            "iPad3,5"   : .iPad4,
            "iPad3,6"   : .iPad4,
            "iPhone6,1" : .iPhone5S,
            "iPhone6,2" : .iPhone5S,
            "iPad4,1"   : .iPadAir1,
            "iPad4,2"   : .iPadAir2,
            "iPad4,4"   : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,5"   : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,6"   : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,7"   : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad4,8"   : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad4,9"   : .iPadMini3,
            "iPhone7,1" : .iPhone6plus,
            "iPhone7,2" : .iPhone6,
            "iPhone8,1" : .iPhone6S,
            "iPhone8,2" : .iPhone6Splus,
            "iPhone8,4" : .iPhoneSE,
            "iPhone9,1" : .iPhone7,
            "iPhone9,2" : .iPhone7plus,
            "iPhone9,3" : .iPhone7,
            "iPhone9,4" : .iPhone7plus,
            ]

        guard let safeModelCode = modelCode else {
            return Model.unrecognized
        }

        guard let modelString = String.init(validatingUTF8: safeModelCode) else {
            return Model.unrecognized
        }

        guard let model = modelMap[modelString] else {
            return Model.unrecognized
        }

        return model
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to keep updating your code everytime Apple adds a new model to a device family, use the method below returning you the model code only.

```
func platform() -> String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let modelCode = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&systemInfo.machine) {
            ptr in String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(ptr))
        }

        return String.fromCString(modelCode!)!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BDLocalizedDevicesModels](https://github.com/bixcorp/BDLocalizedDevicesModels) framework to parse device info and get the name.

Then just call `UIDevice.currentDevice.productName` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

I recently worked on the development of this swift package:

https://github.com/EmilioOjeda/Device

The main advantage it has - I think - is that it is **code-generated**. So whenever a new Xcode version is released, all I have to do is to run a script and get the swift package updated.

How does code generation work?

It reads and parses the devices' data from Xcode's databases (per platform) to identify the device that is running - and provide the information for it.

And it's usage...

```swift
import Device
// or => 'import iPhoneOSDevice' <= iPhoneOS-only device data
// or => 'import tvOSDevice' <= tvOS-only device data

// A representation of the running device - it could be either actual or simulated.
let device = Device.current

// It is 'true' when running on a physical device.
_ = device.isDevice

// It is 'true' when running on a simulator instance.
_ = device.isSimulator

// It is 'true' when the device does not match either simulators or physical devices.
_ = device.isUnknown

// The identifier for the device.
// i.e.: 'iPhone15,3'
let id = device.id

// The known/commercial name of the device.
// i.e.: 'iPhone 14 Pro Max'
let model = device.model
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code for getting the hardware string, but you need to compare these hardware string to know which device it is. I have created a class for that contains almost all the device strings(we're keeping string upto date with new devices). It's easy to use please check

**Swift** : [GitHub/DeviceGuru](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceGuru)

**Objective-C** : [GitHub/DeviceUtil](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceUtil)

```
public func hardwareString() -> String {
  var name: [Int32] = [CTL_HW, HW_MACHINE]
  var size: Int = 2
  sysctl(&name, 2, nil, &size, &name, 0)
  var hw_machine = [CChar](count: Int(size), repeatedValue: 0)
  sysctl(&name, 2, &hw_machine, &size, &name, 0)

  let hardware: String = String.fromCString(hw_machine)!
  return hardware
}
```

Comment: DeviceGuru doesn't seem to have been updated in a while. I wrote a similar package that checks for new updates every day automatically. https://github.com/ptrkstr/Devices

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 3.1**

my two cents for simply calling utsname:

```
    func platform() -> String {
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let size = Int(_SYS_NAMELEN) // is 32, but posix AND its init is 256....

    let s = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {p in

        p.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: size, {p2 in
            return String(cString: p2)
        })

    }
    return s
}
```

as other did, but a bit cleaner about all the intricacy of C/Swift and back.
):

Returns values such as "x86_64"

Answer (score 2):

My simple solution grouped by device and support new devices `iPhone 8` and `iPhone X` in `Swift 3`:

```
public extension UIDevice {
    var modelName: String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }

        switch identifier {
        case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3", "iPhone4,1":
            return "iPhone 4"

        case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2", "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4", "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2", "iPhone8,4":
            return "iPhone 5"

        case "iPhone7,2", "iPhone8,1", "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3", "iPhone10,1", "iPhone10,4":
            return "iPhone 6,7,8"

        case "iPhone7,1", "iPhone8,2", "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4", "iPhone10,2", "iPhone10,5":
            return "iPhone Plus"

        case "iPhone10,3", "iPhone10,6":
            return "iPhone X"

        case "i386", "x86_64":
            return "Simulator"
        default:
            return identifier
        }
    }
}
```

And use:

```
switch UIDevice.current.modelName {
  case "iPhone 4":
  case "iPhone 5":
  case "iPhone 6,7,8":
  case "iPhone Plus":
  case "iPhone X":
  case "Simulator":
  default:
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/5928180) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33495869/5928180). I've created a public [gist](https://gist.github.com/kuyazee/18f026aeed0917c464ef2029fe79d456)

How it can be used

```
let boolean: Bool = UIDevice.isDevice(ofType: .iPhoneX)
// true or false

let specificDevice: DeviceModel.Model = UIDevice.modelType
// iPhone6s, iPhoneX, iPad etc...

let model: DeviceModel = UIDevice.model
// .simulator(let specificDevice), .real(let specificDevice),
// .unrecognizedSimulator(let string), .unrecognized(let string)

let modelName: String = UIDevice.model.name
// iPhone 6, iPhone X, etc...
```

This is the code inside the gist

```
public extension UIDevice {
    public static var modelCode: String {
        if let simulatorModelIdentifier = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] { return simulatorModelIdentifier }
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        return withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
            ptr in String(cString: UnsafeRawPointer(ptr).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self))
        }
    }

    public static var model: DeviceModel {
        // Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/5928180
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let modelCode = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
            ptr in String(cString: UnsafeRawPointer(ptr).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self))
        }

        // Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/33495869/5928180
        if modelCode == "i386" || modelCode == "x86_64" {
            if let simulatorModelCode = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"], let model = DeviceModel.Model(modelCode: simulatorModelCode) {
                return DeviceModel.simulator(model)
            } else if let simulatorModelCode = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
                return DeviceModel.unrecognizedSimulator(simulatorModelCode)
            } else {
                return DeviceModel.unrecognized(modelCode)
            }
        } else if let model = DeviceModel.Model(modelCode: modelCode) {
            return DeviceModel.real(model)
        } else {
            return DeviceModel.unrecognized(modelCode)
        }
    }

    public static var modelType: DeviceModel.Model? {
        return UIDevice.model.model
    }

    public static func isDevice(ofType model: DeviceModel.Model) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.modelType == model
    }
}


public enum DeviceModel {
    case simulator(Model)
    case unrecognizedSimulator(String)
    case real(Model)
    case unrecognized(String)

    public enum Model: String {
        case iPod1            = "iPod 1"
        case iPod2            = "iPod 2"
        case iPod3            = "iPod 3"
        case iPod4            = "iPod 4"
        case iPod5            = "iPod 5"
        case iPad2            = "iPad 2"
        case iPad3            = "iPad 3"
        case iPad4            = "iPad 4"
        case iPhone4          = "iPhone 4"
        case iPhone4S         = "iPhone 4S"
        case iPhone5          = "iPhone 5"
        case iPhone5S         = "iPhone 5S"
        case iPhone5C         = "iPhone 5C"
        case iPadMini1        = "iPad Mini 1"
        case iPadMini2        = "iPad Mini 2"
        case iPadMini3        = "iPad Mini 3"
        case iPadAir1         = "iPad Air 1"
        case iPadAir2         = "iPad Air 2"
        case iPadPro9_7       = "iPad Pro 9.7\""
        case iPadPro9_7_cell  = "iPad Pro 9.7\" cellular"
        case iPadPro10_5      = "iPad Pro 10.5\""
        case iPadPro10_5_cell = "iPad Pro 10.5\" cellular"
        case iPadPro12_9      = "iPad Pro 12.9\""
        case iPadPro12_9_cell = "iPad Pro 12.9\" cellular"
        case iPhone6          = "iPhone 6"
        case iPhone6plus      = "iPhone 6 Plus"
        case iPhone6S         = "iPhone 6S"
        case iPhone6Splus     = "iPhone 6S Plus"
        case iPhoneSE         = "iPhone SE"
        case iPhone7          = "iPhone 7"
        case iPhone7plus      = "iPhone 7 Plus"
        case iPhone8          = "iPhone 8"
        case iPhone8plus      = "iPhone 8 Plus"
        case iPhoneX          = "iPhone X"

        init?(modelCode: String) {
            switch modelCode {
            case "iPod1,1":    self = .iPod1
            case "iPod2,1":    self = .iPod2
            case "iPod3,1":    self = .iPod3
            case "iPod4,1":    self = .iPod4
            case "iPod5,1":    self = .iPod5
            case "iPad2,1":    self = .iPad2
            case "iPad2,2":    self = .iPad2
            case "iPad2,3":    self = .iPad2
            case "iPad2,4":    self = .iPad2
            case "iPad2,5":    self = .iPadMini1
            case "iPad2,6":    self = .iPadMini1
            case "iPad2,7":    self = .iPadMini1
            case "iPhone3,1":  self = .iPhone4
            case "iPhone3,2":  self = .iPhone4
            case "iPhone3,3":  self = .iPhone4
            case "iPhone4,1":  self = .iPhone4S
            case "iPhone5,1":  self = .iPhone5
            case "iPhone5,2":  self = .iPhone5
            case "iPhone5,3":  self = .iPhone5C
            case "iPhone5,4":  self = .iPhone5C
            case "iPad3,1":    self = .iPad3
            case "iPad3,2":    self = .iPad3
            case "iPad3,3":    self = .iPad3
            case "iPad3,4":    self = .iPad4
            case "iPad3,5":    self = .iPad4
            case "iPad3,6":    self = .iPad4
            case "iPhone6,1":  self = .iPhone5S
            case "iPhone6,2":  self = .iPhone5S
            case "iPad4,1":    self = .iPadAir1
            case "iPad4,2":    self = .iPadAir2
            case "iPad4,4":    self = .iPadMini2
            case "iPad4,5":    self = .iPadMini2
            case "iPad4,6":    self = .iPadMini2
            case "iPad4,7":    self = .iPadMini3
            case "iPad4,8":    self = .iPadMini3
            case "iPad4,9":    self = .iPadMini3
            case "iPad6,3":    self = .iPadPro9_7
            case "iPad6,11":   self = .iPadPro9_7
            case "iPad6,4":    self = .iPadPro9_7_cell
            case "iPad6,12":   self = .iPadPro9_7_cell
            case "iPad6,7":    self = .iPadPro12_9
            case "iPad6,8":    self = .iPadPro12_9_cell
            case "iPad7,3":    self = .iPadPro10_5
            case "iPad7,4":    self = .iPadPro10_5_cell
            case "iPhone7,1":  self = .iPhone6plus
            case "iPhone7,2":  self = .iPhone6
            case "iPhone8,1":  self = .iPhone6S
            case "iPhone8,2":  self = .iPhone6Splus
            case "iPhone8,4":  self = .iPhoneSE
            case "iPhone9,1":  self = .iPhone7
            case "iPhone9,2":  self = .iPhone7plus
            case "iPhone9,3":  self = .iPhone7
            case "iPhone9,4":  self = .iPhone7plus
            case "iPhone10,1": self = .iPhone8
            case "iPhone10,2": self = .iPhone8plus
            case "iPhone10,3": self = .iPhoneX
            case "iPhone10,6": self = .iPhoneX
            default:           return nil
            }
        }
    }

    public var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .simulator(let model):         return "Simulator[\(model.rawValue)]"
        case .unrecognizedSimulator(let s): return "UnrecognizedSimulator[\(s)]"
        case .real(let model):              return model.rawValue
        case .unrecognized(let s):          return "Unrecognized[\(s)]"
        }
    }

    public var model: DeviceModel.Model? {
        switch self {
        case .simulator(let model):         return model
        case .real(let model):              return model
        case .unrecognizedSimulator(_):     return nil
        case .unrecognized(_):              return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me

```
var sysinfo = utsname()
uname(&sysinfo)
let data = Data(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, count: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN))
let model = String(cString: [UInt8](data) //iPhone13,1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Simplest way to get model name (marketing name)

Use [private API](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIDevice.h) `-[UIDevice _deviceInfoForKey:]` carefully, you won't be rejected by Apple,

```c
// works on both simulators and real devices, iOS 8 to iOS 12
NSString *deviceModelName(void) {
    // For Simulator
    NSString *modelName = NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment[@"SIMULATOR_DEVICE_NAME"];
    if (modelName.length > 0) {
        return modelName;
    }

    // For real devices and simulators, except simulators running on iOS 8.x
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    NSString *selName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%@ForKey:", @"deviceInfo"];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selName);
    if ([device respondsToSelector:selector]) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
        modelName = [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"marketing-name"];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }
    return modelName;
}
```

## How did I get the key "marketing-name"?

Running on a simulator, `NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment` contains a key named "SIMULATOR_CAPABILITIES", the value of which is a plist file. Then you open the plist file, you will get the model name's key "marketing-name".

Comment: I would not recommend using private APIs

Comment: @Julius You are right. It always works, and don't need to update your code with new Apple devices release.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a new [library](https://github.com/ShawnBaek/DeviceDetector) for detecting apple devices

```swift
import DeviceDetector

let detector = DeviceDetector.shared
let deviceName = detector.currentDeviceName
let deviceSet = detector.currentDevice
        
let information = """
Model: \(deviceName)
iPhone?: \(detector.isiPhone)
iPad?: \(detector.isiPad)
Notch?: \(detector.hasSafeArea)
        
4inch?: \(DeviceSet.iPhone4inchSet.contains(deviceSet))
4.7inch?: \(DeviceSet.iPhone4_7inchSet.contains(deviceSet))
iPhoneSE?: \(DeviceSet.iPhoneSESet.contains(deviceSet))
iPhonePlus?: \(DeviceSet.iPhonePlusSet.contains(deviceSet))
iPadPro?: \(DeviceSet.iPadProSet.contains(deviceSet))
"""
```

Result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);

NSString* deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIDevice {

    public static let hardwareModel: String = {
        var path = [CTL_HW, HW_MACHINE]
        var n = 0
        sysctl(&path, 2, nil, &n, nil, 0)
        var a: [UInt8] = .init(repeating: 0, count: n)
        sysctl(&path, 2, &a, &n, nil, 0)
        return .init(cString: a)
    }()
}

UIDevice.hardwareModel // → iPhone9,3
```

Answer (score 0):

**For swift4.0 and above used below code:**

```
let udid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
let name = UIDevice.current.name
let version = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
let modelName = UIDevice.current.model
let osName = UIDevice.current.systemName
let localized = UIDevice.current.localizedModel

print(udid ?? "")
print(name)
print(version)
print(modelName)
print(osName)
print(localized)
```

Answer (score -2):

In Swift 3 it'd be

```
 UIDevice.current.model
```

Comment: Result I get back is just "iPhone", when I run on any of the simulators.

Comment: This solution returns just model as "iPhone" or "iPod touch". Not the particular device like "iPhone 6s"

Answer (score -2):

```
struct DeviceType {
        static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && Constants.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568
        static let IS_IPHONE_5 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && Constants.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568
        static let IS_IPHONE_6 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && Constants.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667
        static let IS_IPHONE_6P = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && Constants.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736
        static let IS_IPAD = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && Constants.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024
    }
```