# Dynamically Set the Font size in iphone 5 and iphone 6

Tags: ios, fonts, iphone-5, iphone-6

After iOS 8 Apple introduce size classes which is very helpful for the developer. But they give the different font sizes for all iPhones (iPhone 4s , iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6) and iPhone 6 plus, So is there any possible correct way to do the same in iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 .....

I don't want checks please like this 
[Set different font size for iPhone 5 and 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165246/set-different-font-size-for-iphone-5-and-6)

Your suitable and best answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use below macro -

```
// I assume that iPhone 5 Font size 17.0 and iPhone 6 font size 25.0 and default font size 12.0
#define kFONTSize ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568 ? 17.0 :[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667? 25.0: 12.0)
#define kFONT_DEFINE [UIFont fontWithName:AVENIR_LTPRO size:kFONTSize]

txtView.font = kFONT_DEFINE;
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: thank you but i found much better answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065929/size-class-to-identify-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-plus-portrait