# Swift - Make layout smaller for one device

Tags: xcode, swift, layout, autolayout, size-classes

So I don't get the point to develop for 3,5 devices if the layout view is bigger than that, now some of the layouts doesn't fit in the 3.5 devices, what is the best way to solve it, I am already using Size Classes and Auto Layout. Is there any way to make things smaller just for the 3,5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [@HAS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift) for a great extension to get the device. You can simply add his extension to any file you want (outside of the class body).

Then you check your device type like that:

```
let model = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName

if(model == "iPhone 4" || model == "iPhone 4S"){
    //do iPhone 4 stuff
}else{
    //do other stuff
}
```