# Size classes common practice

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, size-classes

When I have a custom designed background for my app, the buttons appear on different places for the different iPhone devices.

Is there an easy way to change the position of the button for one device, and let it have a different position for the others? I know you could make individual storyboards for all the iPhone-types, but that seems a bit outdated.

Comment: Check my answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199110/swift-make-layout-smaller-for-one-device/28199509#28199509

Comment: @ChristianWoerz So from what I understand that extension is only for finding out which device type you're on, and being able to do things programmatically? I'm on the lookout for ways to change the button positions in the interface builder.

Comment: So have you tried using size classes? Which versions of iOS do you support?

Comment: @Wain Yes, but there you can't choose for example so set the button position for a specific device type, or can you? I support iOS7 and 8

Comment: If you equate device to screen size you can, though there are limitations to ios 7 support

Comment: @Wain Okay, so would you say the best solution would be to go for multiple storyboards?

Comment: Generally I'd look yo size classes first because ios 7 won't be running on iPhone 6 devices