# resizing per storyboard issue swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I am wondering if someone can show me how to write this code so it resizes automatically for different screen sizes. I have 4 storyboards with different screen sizes and just want a way to show the code, if this storyboard then (numbers change) follow this code, else (numbers chafe according to storyboard size) this code.

I already tried resizing by adding to each axis number for example / 568 * size.frame.height after each y and height axis and same for x and width of course, but the code becomes too long and complex to read.

Ideally I'd like an if statement saying if this screen size then it's storyboard 'this' then go to this code..

```
pianoButtonsWaterDropFrames = [
            cNote: (CGRect(x: 33 , y: 40 , width: 20, height: 35), CGRect(x: 33, y: 360, width: 20, height: 35)),
            dNote: (CGRect(x: 66 , y: 42 , width: 20, height: 35), CGRect(x: 66, y: 360, width: 20, height: 35)),
            eNote: (CGRect(x: 99 , y: 41 , width: 20, height: 35), CGRect(x: 99 , y: 360, width: 20, height: 35)),
            fNote: (CGRect(x: 132, y: 48, width: 20, height: 35), CGRect(x: 132, y: 360, width: 20, height: 35)),
            gNote: (CGRect(x: 165, y: 39, width: 20, height: 35), CGRect(x: 165, y: 360, width: 20, height: 35)),
            aNote: (CGRect(x: 198, y: 57, width: 20, height: 35), CGRect(x: 198, y: 360, width: 20, height: 35)),
            bNote: (CGRect(x: 231, y: 60, width: 20, height: 35), CGRect(x: 231, y: 360, width: 20, height: 35)),
            cFourNote: (CGRect(x: 263, y: 54, width: 20, height: 35), CGRect(x: 263, y: 360, width: 20, height: 35))
        ]
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HAS answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift) to check, which iPhone your app is running on. Then you can use a switch statement and call different methods:

```
let modelName = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName

switch modelName{
    case "iPhone 3G", "iPhone 3GS":
    method1()
    case "iPhone 4", "iPhone 4S":
    method2()
default:
    println("no size found")
}
```