# How to filter apple devices on the appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store, device

I am publishing a game and i want the device to be at least iphone5s / ipad4 / ipad mini 4, since I want my game to run on 60 fps.
Is there a way to achieve it through settings?
Is it commonplace to post minimum requirements in app's description?

Comment: can you organise by processor type rather than explicit device ?

Comment: We can actually run on ipad4 and it soesn't support armv64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only limit by device (like iPad or iPhone) or by S.O(like iOS 9.1+), you cannot limit in the App Store by model.

You may send a warning or even close the app (not recommend, and probably will be rejected in the App Store) to the user using a older device, or put this in the description of the app store "App runs better in iPhone 5s+"

To check the version, look at this answer.

[iOS: How to determine the current iPhone/device model in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift)

Comment: The problem here is that the game will be a paid app. So i want prevent users from disappointement.

Comment: Nothing you can do about this, you should just put it very clear in the app description.