# Comparing two identical string, but they are evaluated as false

Tags: swift

I am trying to have a certain block of code only be executed if the users iPhone is of a certain model. I am testing on the iOS Simulator, so I used the `iPhoneModel()` function bellow to get the device model for the simulator and printed it to the console and pasted it into the if condition in the `compare()` function.

```
func iPhoneModel() -> String {
    var sysinfo = utsname()
    uname(&sysinfo) // ignore return value
    return NSString(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, length: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN), encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)! as String
}

func compare() {
    if iPhoneModel() == "x86_64" {
        print("It Worked!")
    }
}
```

The `iPhoneModel()` function should return an identical string and the statement should be true, but instead it is false. I have even printed both strings to console to check them with my own eyes and they both appear to be identical, yet the computer thinks otherwise. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you use a debugger to step thorough the code one by one?

Comment: Print lengths of both strings to make sure there's no trailing whitespace in there.

Comment: Also maybe convert the NSString to a regular string before comparing

Comment: _SYS_NAMELEN == 256 is buffer size in `struct utsname`, not the actual size of the string. Therefore the returned string has a bunch of trailing NUL characters. – Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift for various working methods.

Comment: Thanks! looks like that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just strip out the null characters...

```
func iPhoneModel() -> String {
    var sysinfo = utsname()
    uname(&sysinfo) // ignore return value

    var iPhoneModel = NSString(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, length: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN), encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)! as String

    iPhoneModel = iPhoneModel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\0", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

    return iPhoneModel
}
```