# How to resize UIImageView programmatically in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, resize, ios9, xcode7

I am trying to resize programmatically a UIImageView based on the device screen size, but I can´t make it work. Nothing changes.

Here´s my code:

```
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    print(screenSize.height)

    imgLogo.image = AppKit.appLogo

    switch screenSize.height {
    case 736.0:
        print("iPhone 6 Plus")
        imgLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 80 ,80)
    case 667.0:
        print("iPhone 6")
        imgLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 60, 60)
    case 568.0:
        print("iPhone 5S")
        imgLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)
    case 480.0:
        print("iPhone 4S")
        imgLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 40, 40)
    default: break
```

The View Mode in Interface Builder is set to "Aspect Fit". I am also using Auto Layout with no constraints to the UIImageView width and height.

What´s the problem with this code?

Comment: Using that code, renders a low quality image.

Comment: Both methods render low quality images.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating this helper method:

```
func resizedImage (widthScale: CGFloat, heightScale: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let img = AppKit.appLogo
    let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(img.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(widthScale, heightScale))
    let hasAlpha = true
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
    img.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Usage is:

```
imgLogo.image = resizedImage(0.3, heightScale: 0.3)
```

Answer (score -2):

Comparing floats with as your switch statement does is not reliable.
Try identifying the phone by its model

[See this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/1305067)

Comment: I don´t see the point of this since when I execute the code and change between simulators, it prints the correct device. The problem is not identifying the device model, but now making any changes to the UIImageView.