# Check Motion&Fitness option is available in settings

Tags: ios, iphone

I've checked whether motion&fitness is enabled in my app. I've checked the below code to check this.

```
if([CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable])
    {
    }
```

This returns FALSE when motion&fitness is disabled in settings. But the motion&fitness option is not there in iPhone 5 and lower versions. So I want to know whether the device model is iPhone 5s or higher. Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check motion then use

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMSensorRecorder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CMSensorRecorder/isAuthorizedForRecording

iOS 9 and above, CMSensorRecorder class, In that they introduce method to check if your app is authorized for Motion & Fitness:

If you are using Swift the use following

class `func isAuthorizedForRecording() -> Bool

if Objective C then

```
+ (BOOL)isAuthorizedForRecording
```

---

if you just want to check device model then use following method

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType]   // ex: UIDevice4GiPhone
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString] // ex: @"iPhone 4G"
```

to getting complete list of model

```
#import <sys/utsname.h> // import it in your header or implementation file.

NSString* deviceName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

after printing device name you will get one of following output

```
@"i386"      on 32-bit Simulator
@"x86_64"    on 64-bit Simulator
@"iPod1,1"   on iPod Touch
@"iPod2,1"   on iPod Touch Second Generation
@"iPod3,1"   on iPod Touch Third Generation
@"iPod4,1"   on iPod Touch Fourth Generation
@"iPod7,1"   on iPod Touch 6th Generation
@"iPhone1,1" on iPhone
@"iPhone1,2" on iPhone 3G
@"iPhone2,1" on iPhone 3GS
@"iPad1,1"   on iPad
@"iPad2,1"   on iPad 2
@"iPad3,1"   on 3rd Generation iPad
@"iPhone3,1" on iPhone 4 (GSM)
@"iPhone3,3" on iPhone 4 (CDMA/Verizon/Sprint)
@"iPhone4,1" on iPhone 4S
@"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5 (model A1428, AT&T/Canada)
@"iPhone5,2" on iPhone 5 (model A1429, everything else)
@"iPad3,4" on 4th Generation iPad
@"iPad2,5" on iPad Mini
@"iPhone5,3" on iPhone 5c (model A1456, A1532 | GSM)
@"iPhone5,4" on iPhone 5c (model A1507, A1516, A1526 (China), A1529 | Global)
@"iPhone6,1" on iPhone 5s (model A1433, A1533 | GSM)
@"iPhone6,2" on iPhone 5s (model A1457, A1518, A1528 (China), A1530 | Global)
@"iPad4,1" on 5th Generation iPad (iPad Air) - Wifi
@"iPad4,2" on 5th Generation iPad (iPad Air) - Cellular
@"iPad4,4" on 2nd Generation iPad Mini - Wifi
@"iPad4,5" on 2nd Generation iPad Mini - Cellular
@"iPad4,7" on 3rd Generation iPad Mini - Wifi (model A1599)
@"iPhone7,1" on iPhone 6 Plus
@"iPhone7,2" on iPhone 6
@"iPhone8,1" on iPhone 6S
@"iPhone8,2" on iPhone 6S Plus
@"iPhone8,4" on iPhone SE
```

If you want in Swift please use below link

[iOS: How to determine the current iPhone/device model in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift/26962452#26962452)