# The models name of Apple devices

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

How can I know the models name of Apple devices ? For example, the model name of iPhone 4 are: "iPhone3,1","iPhone3,2","iPhone3,3". For iPhone 6s the model name is "iPhone8,1". I have founded these names on this website, but is there an updated official website where I can found the models name ? Because for example I don't know the model name of iPhone SE, and all those will come after. How do you find the models name ?

Comment: From https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17525: "Apple doesn't document these identifiers." – This seems to be pretty much up-to-date: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models.

Answer (score 0):

The user HAS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/1894067) maded a nice function swift 2.x compatible, usually I use it in my project :

```
import UIKit

public extension UIDevice {

    var modelName: String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }

        switch identifier {
        case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
        case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
        case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
        case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
        case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
        case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
        case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
        case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
        case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
        case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
        case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
        case "iPhone8,4":                               return "iPhone SE"
        case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
        case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
        case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
        case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
        case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
        case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
        case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
        case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
        case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
        case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4", "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":return "iPad Pro"
        case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
        case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
        default:                                        return identifier
        }
    }

}
```

To use it:

```
let modelName = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName
```