# How can I know which iPhone am I using?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I type `UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom` I can make sure it's iPhone, not other devide (`.Phone`).

How can I ensure myself which iPhone am I using (except display resolution measurement)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-determine-device-types-and-ios-versions/