# Swift creating UIButton programmatically with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, constraints

I'm wondering how can I create a UIButton programmatically with a dynamic height depending of the device.
Let's say that I create the button like this:

```
bigButton = BigButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width , height: 60))
```

When setting the height, I need to put an integer, but I would like this to be 60px if display is for iPhone 6, 50px if iPhone 5... and so on.

I know how to do that if I create the button with IB, using the constraints and I could use a percentage height proportion, but since I need to create the button programmatically I'm kind of stuck with that. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just add a height constraint programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of something you can do:

```
var dynamicHeight: CGFloat
switch UIDevice().type {
    case .iPhone4:
        dynamicHeight = 40
    case .iPhone5:
        dynamicHeight = 50
    case .iPhone5S:
        dynamicHeight = 50
    case .iPhone6:
        dynamicHeight = 60
    case .iPhone6plus:
        dynamicHeight = 70
    default:
        dynamicHeight = 40
}

bigButton = BigButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width , height: dynamicHeight))
```

The method of retrieving the device type was taken from [iOS: How to determine iphone model in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27759550/1420793).