# Is it possible to define different background image for each ios device?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

For example, set the background of iphone 5 to image1 and background of iphone 6 to image2, and a third different image for iphone 6+

How can I achieve this using Interface Builder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26028918/3141234

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov thanks for the link. Would you know if it's possible to set different background images using 'Size Classes' in xcode ?

Comment: Size classes aren't meant to differentiate between devices as your question describes. If you were to use them in your context it would only differentiate iPhone from iPad.

Comment: @Aaron, I see. Thank you for clarifying this. I don't know why I keep thinking that size classes can be used to differentiate between different iphone versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically you could do something like this (this assumes portrait only):

```
enum Device {

    case iPhone5
    case iPhone6
    case iPhone6P

    static var sizeClass: Device {

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

        switch screenWidth {
        case _ where screenWidth < 375:
            return .iPhone5
        case 414:
            return iPhone6P
        default:
            return .iPhone6
        }
    } 
}
```

Then where you set the image:

```
    switch Device.sizeClass {
    case .iPhone5:
        // set image
    case .iPhone6:
        // set image
    case .iPhone6P:
        // set image
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't handle rotations.

Comment: Why would it not handle rotations?