# Check if device supports UIFeedbackGenerator in iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, taptic-engine

In iOS 10, there is a new api which allows developers to make use of the taptic engine, UIFeedbackGenerator.

While this api is available in iOS 10, it only works on the new devices, iPhone 7 and 7 plus.  It does not works on older devices including the 6S or 6S Plus, even those have a taptic engine.  I guess the taptic engine on the 7 and 7 plus is a different more powerful one.

I can't seem to find a way to see if the device supports using the new api.  I would like to replace some vibrate code with taptic code, where it makes sense.

Edit:

Adding the 3 concrete subclasses for search purposes:
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator
UINotificationFeedbackGenerator
UISelectionFeedbackGenerator

Edit 2:

I have a theory but no iPhone 7 device to test it so if you have one, give it a shot.  UIFeedbackGenerator has a methods called prepare().  When printing out an instance of UIImpactFeedbackGenerator, I noticed that it printed a property named "prepared" which would show 0.  Calling prepare() in simulator or on iPhone 6S and then printing out the instance still shows prepared as 0. Can someone call prepare() on an instance of UIImpactFeedbackGenerator from an iPhone7 and then print the instance to console to see if prepared is set to 1? This value is not exposed but there may be a way to get this info w/o using private apis.

Comment: According to what I read, you don't need to check if the device supports these APIs. Calls to them will be silent when called on older devices.

Comment: @AndyIbanez I do need to check for my own purposes.  I am switching between a vibrate and a taptic feedback, I would like to not play both at the same time on devices that support it.

Comment: We fall back to a standard "device vibration" if it's not available, as this was previously used in prior OS versions and on older hardware. Need to know if it's possible to do the haptic way or not.

Comment: @BenGuild can you provide a link to docs about this.  I actually tried this and was not getting a vibration.

Comment: @KrisGellci As mentioned, I also need to know if this is possible. Someone mentioned that `UIDevice` has some flags on it that perhaps could be checked, but it's not a public API.

Comment: @KrisGellci If "edit 2" works for you, please post another solution below.

Answer (score 15):

So, apparently this can be done with a private API call.

**Objective-C:**

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] valueForKey:@"_feedbackSupportLevel"];`

**Swift:**

`UIDevice.currentDevice().valueForKey("_feedbackSupportLevel");`

---

**... These methods seem to return:**

- **`0`** = Taptic not available
- **`1`** = First generation (tested on an iPhone 6s) ... which does NOT support `UINotificationFeedbackGenerator`, etc.
- **`2`** = Second generation (tested on an iPhone 7) ... which **does** support it.

---

**Unfortunately,** there are two caveats here:

1. Using these could get your app rejected by Apple during the App Store's App Review, but there doesn't seem to be any other way currently.
2. We don't know what the **actual** values represent.

Special thanks to **Tim Oliver** and **Steve T-S** for helping test this with different devices. https://twitter.com/TimOliverAU/status/778105029643436033

Comment: Definitely worth a Radar to expose the availability-checks to the public API.

Comment: @BenGuild Why an app using this method could be rejected by Apple ?

Comment: This no longer works with iOS 11. Will cause a crash with `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _feedbackSupportLevel.'`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best way is to check the device's model using:

```
public extension UIDevice
    public func platform() -> String {
        var sysinfo = utsname()
        uname(&sysinfo) // ignore return value
        return String(bytes: Data(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, count: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN)), encoding: .ascii)!.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)
    }
}
```

The platform names for iPhone 7 and 7 plus are: `"iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3", "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4"`

Source: [iOS: How to determine the current iPhone/device model in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift)

You can create a function:

```
public extension UIDevice {
    public var hasHapticFeedback: Bool {
        return ["iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3", "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4"].contains(platform())
    } 
}
```

Comment: But then your problem is when the next iPhones come out, and they apparently don't support it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem, and the code should be updated if needed. But currently, this is one possible solution instead of using a private API.

Comment: Another problem is that the user can disable Haptic Feedback in the device settings, which won't be covered by this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have extended [chrisamanse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41298303/4735187). It extraxts the generation number from the model identifier and checks if it is equal or greater than 9. Should work with future iPhone models unless Apple decides to introduce a new internal naming scheme.

```
public extension UIDevice {

    var modelIdentifier: String {
        var sysinfo = utsname()
        uname(&sysinfo) // ignore return value
        return String(bytes: Data(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, count: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN)), encoding: .ascii)!.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)
    }


    var hasHapticFeedback: Bool {

        // assuming that iPads and iPods don't have a Taptic Engine
        if !modelIdentifier.contains("iPhone") {
            return false
        }

        // e.g. will equal to "9,5" for "iPhone9,5"
        let subString = String(modelIdentifier[modelIdentifier.index(modelIdentifier.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)..<modelIdentifier.endIndex])

        // will return true if the generationNumber is equal to or greater than 9
        if let generationNumberString = subString.components(separatedBy: ",").first,
            let generationNumber = Int(generationNumberString),
            generationNumber >= 9 {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

}
```

Use it like so:

```
if UIDevice.current.hasHapticFeedback {
    // work with taptic engine
} else {
    // fallback for older devices
}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, that doesn't depend on private API, less headaches and sweating for the future, thanks!