# How to check if I am running on iPhone6s Plus simulator

Tags: ios, xctest, uidevice, fbsnapshottestcase

I have snapshot tests which are per device. I want to check in my tests that I am running on a particular simulator that has a snapshot for it.

So for example I want to test that current simulator is iPhone6sPlus9.2 
since the snapshot wasn't recorded for the many other simulator types I have.

I've tried many variations like:

```
(lldb) po [[UIDevice currentDevice] platform]
x86_64

(lldb) po [[UIDevice currentDevice] hwmodel]
MacBookPro11,2

(lldb) po [[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType]
0x0000000000000002

(lldb) po [[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]
iPhone Simulator

(lldb) po [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]
iPhone

(lldb) po [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]
iPhone

(lldb) po [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]
iPhone OS

(lldb) po [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
9.2

(lldb) po [UIDevice currentDevice]
<UIDevice: 0x7fccf060a480>

(lldb) po [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]
iPhone Simulator // I WANT TO KNOW THAT IT IS IPHONE6SPLUS 9.2
```

and also the code from here https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/

and the code from

//  UIDevice+YYAdd.h
//  YYKit https://github.com/ibireme/YYKit

but both are returning irrelevant values such as "x86" for the device type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift

Comment: No good. Thats physical device. I need simulator type

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[NSProcessInfo processInfo].environment[@"SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"]`

It will return `iPhone8,2` for the iPhone6s Plus Simulator.

Attention: You may have your reasons to write code against a specific simulator model, but it's generally not a good idea. You should instead dynamically adapt screen sizes, check the availability of APIs / Frameworks and so on...