# How to make the app can only be more than iPhone 5s installation?

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS APP :

How to make the app can only be more than iPhone 5s  installation ? Thanks.

Comment: please check this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/6619234

Comment: @seggy That link is not appropriate for this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I don't want to get the device model.

Comment: @rmaddy i know but that is iinformation purpose only..

Comment: You can't  make this, because latest iOS version 10 compatible devices are from iPhone 5. So you can make only be more than iPhone 5 installation.

Comment: Thanks . This is not what I want

Comment: App only supports more than iPhone 5s , iOS 10 support iPhone 5 and 5 c,How do you solve that?

Comment: @YounG, wait for iOS11. Then you are able to restrict iPhone 5s. ;)

Comment: @Yun CHEN It's gonna be great. But Can't wait ...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not restrict the device for installation. What you can restrict is only iOS version running on a device.

Answer (score 0):

You can only restrict IOS version.

Currently best solution for your situation is

Restrict OS version from IOS 10 and your app will available only for thous iPhones, iPads and iPod

```
iPhone 6s
iPhone 6s Plus
iPhone 6
iPhone 6 Plus
iPhone SE
iPhone 5s
iPhone 5c
iPhone 5

iPad Pro 12.9-inch
iPad Pro 9.7-inch
iPad Air 2
iPad Air
iPad 4th generation
iPad 3rd generation
iPad 2
iPad mini 4
iPad mini 3
iPad mini 2
iPad mini

iPod touch 6th generation
```

For this solution you can loose users because not all devices is updated to IOS 10, but by statistics on September most of user already installed IOS 10

ref. [enter link description here](https://9to5mac.com/2016/10/10/ios-10-now-installed-on-two-thirds-of-devices-faster-adoption-than-any-previous-ios-update/)

[image]

Comment: but, If you will restrict it to iOS 10, then users having iOS 9 on iPhone 5 or 6 would not be able to use your App.

Comment: Yes, You are right but most of users already updated to IOS 10, of course you will loose users but they are not big. Anyway this is cost of restriction :)

Comment: App only supports more than iPhone 5s , iOS 10 support iPhone 5 and 5 c,How do you solve that?

Comment: @YounG, you can't restrict devices fro the installation. But What you can do is - When user Launches App for the first time , Check the device and If the device is not more than iPhone 5s, then Show an alert to user something like. "Your device is not compatible to run this app" and then force quit the app .

Comment: @Krishna Datt Shula    App Store audit can pass?

Comment: Yes, i think they will not have any problem with this. I have not used restriction on device in any app but I have used force quit in my app which has been passed by App Store. So you can try it.

Comment: @Krishna Datt Shula,  Thanks!

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla  if you will force quit app Apple Store will reject if they will see that, Apple is not allow force quit app only user and OS can quit app
Usually they are checking on latest devices and they don't see that problems , but once they will see that kind feature they will reject app
I had like that experience

Comment: @Grigori Jlavyan,Yes, you are right! force quit app Apple Store will reject if they will see that.