# Is it possible to have one layout per device instead of auto layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios-autolayout

In XCode, I would like to have a different layout according to the device used. For example, if it's an iPad, I would like an image to be aligned to the left with some text to the right, while on an iPhone 7, I would like the image to be above the text. A little like a responsive website where we can manage the layouts according to the device width.

Is it possible in XCode using Storyboards? Or should I just keep working using the auto layout feature?

Thanks!

Comment: you really should use autolayout, one day when apple decides to add a new screen size for their phones, your apps layout will break without an update which could take you a while to push out depending how much UI your app has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `autolayout`, we can achieve the different layout on different screen sizes. You can change `constants values` for difference size classes in Storyboard.

Step:-

- Select the constant we want to change the value in other size classes.
- In the attribute inspector after selecting the constant, you can see the value of the constant. Right beside you can see the PLUS (+) sign, left of the "constant".
- Click on it and select your size class that you want.
- Give it a new value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model-in-swift) to answer your question.

However, if as you said you only want different displays for iPads and iPhones, you can differentiate them in this simple way:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

    // Show iPad UI

} else {

    // Show iPhone UI

}
```