# How to convert metric/Inch to CGSize - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgsize

I need to render a PDF for a given metric size. I can render a PDF in iOS coordinates but how can I convert i.e. 1mm to points.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The size of a point depends on the device. You will need a reference table and check which device you are running on. You can find more information about size conversion [here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/10/23/the-point-of-resolution-independence-ios-and-iphone-6-plus/). And [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model-in-swift) will help you get the device model you are running your app on.

Comment: Can you update your answer since the link is broken