# How to determine current iphone version in swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

I need to know which iPhone version is currently being using in my app? For ex:- If app is installed in iPhone 5. It should give current  version is iPhone 5. Any help would appreciate.

Comment: Search in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model-in-swift

Comment: THANKS. WAS  REALLY HELPFULL.