# Show different Xib files based on the user's phone in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, xib, custom-keyboard

I'm using a Xib file and code programmatically to create a custom keyboard. I want different buttons based on the phone the user uses. Vary for traits does not exactly work for what I want. I'd rather make multiple Xib files and have them show based on the on the phone size of the user. Anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: You could load the xib or storyboard file programmatically based on the screen size for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this answer to grab the user's device model: [Device Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model-in-swift) and then load in your Xib according to what the user is currently using.

```
let vc = UIViewController(nibName: "name", bundle: nil)
```