# Add text of UILabel from database by loop - Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, database, uilabel, character

I'm creating `UILabel` by `for` loop and I wanna adding text in the `UILabel` from database, the text in database a `String` but I'm converting `String` to `Array Characters`, for example I've 4 labels and 4 characters (A, B, C, D), **I want to add each characters in one label how can I do that ??**

I wanna create like this :

[image]

And this my code :

```
func createTarget(id: Int) {

    listdata = dbHelpr.getDatabase(rowId: id)
    var targetHeigt = CGFloat()
    let viewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
    
    if viewWidth == 320 {
        targetHeigt = 2.5
    } else {
        targetHeigt = 5
    }
    
    for data in listdata { // listdata is (Database) has a variable (ans)
        let yAxis : CGFloat = (self.view.frame.height) * 60%
        let i = data.ans.length
        // char count
        let width: Int = Int(view.frame.size.width) - 40
        // frame width
        var targetWidth: Int = (width - (i - 1) * 5) / i
        if targetWidth > 50 {
            targetWidth = 50
        }

        let totalWidth: Int = (targetWidth * i) + ((i - 1) * 5)

        for x in 0..<i {
            let currentWidth: Int = (width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2) + (x * targetWidth) + (x * 5) + 20
            let targetLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(currentWidth), y: yAxis, width: CGFloat(targetWidth), height: 50))
            targetLabel.backgroundColor = .white
            targetLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
            targetLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            targetLabel.textAlignment = .center
            targetLabel.textColor = .black

            for tar in data.ans.characters {
                targetLabel.text = String(tar)
            }

            self.view.addSubview(targetLabel)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my code above show me this :

[image]

> My output :
>
> `D`
>
> `D`
>
> `D`
>
> `D`

And when I edited and added my code to :

```
for data in listdata { // listdata is (Database) has a variable (ans)

    let tar = data.ans.characters.map{String($0)}

    lblLabel.text = tar.joined(separator: " ")

}
```

This a result of my code above :

[image]

> My output :
>
> `D C B A`
>
> `D C B A`
>
> `D C B A`
>
> `D C B A`

**What's the best solve to create label whit characters exactly like 1st picture ??**

Comment: Are your 4 labels already created (in the Storyboard perhaps).  Do you have @IBOutlets to them?

Comment: Please edit your first code block by inserting print statements to cover everything.  Then show us the results.

Comment: Is each block is separate UILabel?

Comment: No I created my label programmatically @vacawama

Comment: What do you do with a label after you create it?

Comment: for each char you create new label. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm editing my question now @Smartcat

Comment: I'm creating my labels with for loop and I wanna to add text to each label from SQLite database, if you want to see how did I created my labels see this question and my [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544072/organize-and-adjust-the-uilabel-position-per-devices-swift-3) @vacawama

Comment: Create a empty array and fetch each characters into it. And create labels after adding the characters into array.

Comment: My string is a array and I converted my string to characters @Alwin

Comment: Update *this* question with the complete code that creates the labels and sets their text.

Comment: I'm adding complete code in my question @vacawama

Comment: I updated my answer for your current code.  Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already creating one label for each character, so there is no need to loop over them again.

Try this:

```
for (x, tar) in data.ans.characters.reversed().enumerated() {
    let currentWidth: Int = (width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2) + (x * targetWidth) + (x * 5) + 20
    let targetLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(currentWidth), y: yAxis, width: CGFloat(targetWidth), height: 50))
    targetLabel.backgroundColor = .white
    targetLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    targetLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    targetLabel.textAlignment = .center
    targetLabel.textColor = .black

    targetLabel.text = String(tar)

    self.view.addSubview(targetLabel)
}
```

Comment: It's working, but my characters get me left to right ( A B C D) I wanna right to left like this (D C B A) how can I do that ?

Comment: `for (x, tar) in data.ans.characters.reversed().enumerated() {`