# Detect iOS Device Type on iPhone app that is running on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

So I have a situation where I have developed an iPhone application, that can be run on the iPad on the 4S resolution (the default way apple handles running iPhone app on the iPad).
But now, I want to understand user activity for the user's that are using the app on the iPad, to see if it makes sense for me to build an iPad Version of the app.
But, when I log `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` it always returns iphone.
One solution I had thought of, was to check the screen resolution (since no one uses the 4/4S anyway now), but with launch of the iPad Pro, apple runs iPhone apps on the iPad Pro using the iPhone 7 resolution. In that case, I have no way to know if the user is running the app on the iPhone or iPad.

Comment: If you only care about whether the device is an iPad or iPhone, why not use `UIDevice.current.model`?

Comment: you are talking about iPad or iPod?

Comment: here is your answer [StackOVerFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/5259363)

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
+(BOOL) isIPad
{
    BOOL isPad;
    NSRange range = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] rangeOfString:@"iPad"];

    if(range.location==NSNotFound)
    {
        isPad=NO;


    }
    else {
        isPad=YES;
    }

    return isPad;
}
```