# How to detect iPhone X (Ionic - cordova app)

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, iphone-x

I need to make some changes to my app but only for iPhone X.

The app is Apache Cordova based (with Ionic framework).

Is there a **cordova plugin** to detect the iPhone X? If the answer is no, which is the best method to know if the user has an iPhone X **in javascript**?

Thanks

Comment: What changes do you have in mind?

Comment: @str Does it really matter?

Comment: @Jackowski Yes it does. Depending on what has to be changed, there are much better ways to achieve it than to detect the device in the first place.

Comment: Actually I need to add another part to the app only for this device. Unfortunately these things doesn't depend to the new SDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check: `var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();`

From [Ionic bundle.js](https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js)

```
/**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name ionic.Platform#device
     * @description Return the current device (given by cordova).
     * @returns {object} The device object.
     */
    device: function() {
      return window.device || {};
    },
```

---

Also check [cordova-plugin-device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/)

**Properties**

```
device.cordova       // returns CDV_VERSION
 device.model
 device.platform     // always returns iOS
 device.uuid
 device.version
 device.manufacturer // always returns  Apple
 device.isVirtual    // not relevant
 device.serial
```

This plugin calls [CDVDevice.m](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/master/src/ios/CDVDevice.m) -> `UIDevice` so if you still cannot fetch `iPhone X` worth to find the way how to detect it in Obj-C and change `CDVDevice.m`.

---

Also check this QA: [iOS devices return different format device model, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903483/ios-devices-return-different-format-device-model-why)

Comment: Does `device.model` return "iPhone X" though?

Comment: @johnborges well, try it yourself :)

Comment: With simulator it returns "x86", how can we test it? Also looking at this question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x)) it seems impossible to detect iPhone X

Comment: @ErnestoSchiavo run it on real device, simulators will always return `x86` or `x86_64`

Comment: Well, we have to wait iPhone X :)

Comment: OSX will always return "x86_64" device or emulator as per documentation.

Comment: The question: "How to detect iPhone X (Ionic app)". OSX will always return "x86_64" device or emulator as per documentation. There is no right answer for this yet. Detecting an iPhone X is very different than OSX.

Comment: Can anyone yet confirm what a real iPhone X device returns for `device.model`?

Comment: @DaveAlden `iPhoneX`

Comment: `cordova-plugin-device` reported `device.model` for a hardware iPhoneX as `iPhone10,6`

Answer (score 5):

#### For cordova

using [cordova-plugin-device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/) plugin like so:

`window.device.model`

will give:

**`iPhone10,3` or `iPhone10,6`**

See [doc](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models#iPhone):

[image]

#### For browser

see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46192822/5832547)

Answer (score 5):

I put together this es6 to check for **iphone 10** and above

```
const isIphoneX = () => {
    try {
        const iphoneModel = window.device.model;
        const m = iphoneModel.match(/iPhone(\d+),?(\d+)?/);
        const model = +m[1];

        if (model >= 10) { // is iphone X
            return true;
        }
    } catch (e) { }

    return false;
}
```

** EDIT **

I believe I was using `cordova-plugin-device` as my project was not an ionic application. I rewrote the regex so it could work with `ionic.Platform.device().model` too.

Comment: you don't think it should be ```const model = +m[0];``` ?

Comment: @AlexisCaffa javascript always dumps the full match into the `0` index so I used the `1` index for the first back-reference (which is in parenthesis)

Comment: hai @Jacksonkr, not all models> = 10 are iphone X and above. There are exceptions for iPhone 8 (iPhone10,4) & 8 Plus (iPhone10,5).

Answer (score 3):

I did the following using the built in ionic.Platform.device() method. I don't think it's necessary to install a whole new plugin if you are already using ionic.

```
let model = ionic.Platform.device().model
$scope.deviceIphonex = model.includes('iPhone10')
```

I can then use this anywhere in my app and do things specifically for the iphone X.

Answer (score 0):

fix @Jacksonkr answer and thank you @Made in Moon for providing information regarding the iphone10.3 and iphone10.6 models. You can use this for get device iphone X and above

```
export default () => {
  try {
    const exceptions = ['iPhone10,3', 'iPhone10,6'];
    const iphoneModel = Device.model;
    const m = iphoneModel.match(/iPhone(\d+),?(\d+)?/);
    const model = +m[1];

    if (model >= 11) {
      // is iphone X
      return true;
    } else if (model === 10) {
      // iPhone10,3 = iPhone X
      // iPhone10,4 = iPhone 8
      // iPhone10,5 = iPhone 8 Plus
      // iPhone10,6 = iPhone Xs
      return exceptions.includes(iphoneModel);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  return false;
};
```