# ARKit: how to correctly check for supported devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, arkit

I'm using `ARKit` but it is not a core functionality in my app, so I'm not setting the `arkit` key in the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`. I'm setting the directive `@available(iOS 11.0, *)`, but `ARKit` requires an **A9** processor or above (that is, **iPhone 6S** or newer...)

What the best way to check that? I've found a workaround that involves [checking the device model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model) in several places, but it looks like it's a bit complicated. And would this be rejected in a review for the Store?

Answer (score 9):

You should check the `isSupported` boolean provided by the `ARConfiguration` class for this.

[From the Apple Developer Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2923553-issupported)

> **`isSupported`**
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the current device supports this session configuration class.
>
> All `ARKit` configurations require an iOS device with an A9 or later processor. If your app otherwise supports other devices and **offers augmented reality as a secondary feature**, use this property to determine whether to offer AR-based features to the user.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that I'd like to check before showing the view controller that handles AR...

Comment: You don’t even need an instance — `isSupported` is a class property, and the class always exists in iOS 11 regardless of whether you can do anything useful wth an instance. Just `if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported { ... }` is all you need to gate functionality before showing an AR view.

Answer (score 6):

Just check ARConfiguration availability.

```
if (ARConfiguration.isSupported) {

      // Great! let have experience of ARKIT
} else {
     // Sorry! you don't have ARKIT support in your device
}
```

Comment: FYI, in iOS 11.0.x, whenever calling ARConfiguration.isSupported method, it took 0.001~0.005 seconds.

It would be better manage with cache for a lot of calling this method.

Comment: @DongjinSuh although caching such a static property may sound a good idea, I don't think that 0.001~0.005 seconds would be a problem, especially that Apple themselves recommended checking for the property directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution [Ar support or not](https://github.com/viromedia/viro/issues/492#issuecomment-453934878)

```
// Get array containing installed apps
var installedApps = require("react-native-installed-packages");
let appArray = installedApps.getApps();

// Check app_array for ar core package
var arPackage = appArray.find(function (_package) {
  return _package == "com.google.ar.core";
});

if (typeof arPackage === "undefined") {
  console.log("AR not support");
} else {
  console.log("AR support");
}
```