# iOS App with no story board (Size classes and Device type limitations)

Tags: ios, design-patterns, uikit

Lets say I don't want to use a `UIStoryboard` in my app. Apple pitches `UIStoryboards` hard and they also pitch the ability for `UIStoryboards` to allow you to create a universal app with ease.

I don't want to do this though. So, without listing my long list of reasons my first question is:

Is it smart/acceptable to remove story boards?

Second. Lets say I want to check stuff like Device type to make decisions about what UI to display? [I can find plenty of `UIDevice` extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model) that allow for this with with one limitation. If you use these `UIDevice` extensions when on a simulator you have no way of knowing what the simulator is simulating. So, testing your app on the simulator is not longer an option.

Finally, lets say I used the Size Class API's that Apple provides to try and make UI Code decisions with out a `UIStoryboard`. Is there any way to get a reference to these size classes pre view loading? The classes only seem to be on `UIView` and are not available when making window level decisions on app launch.

Comment: Do not use any of those UIDevice extensions. Base your layout on view size. This allows your app to work on any device and any new screen sizes without updates and it allows your app to support multi-tasking on iPads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it smart/acceptable to remove story boards?

Sure. Building your UI either in code or interface builder is really up to you, up to the team, or up to the company. If that's only your question, this thread would be closed as that is opinion-based. In your second question, I don't think that's a question.

As for your last question, I'm attempting to answer this question though I do not fully understand it. Perhaps this would help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection

And `autolayout` should be the answer to that.

Comment: Thanks Glen. `UITraitCollection` is what I was looking for.