# Swift 4: iOS Simulator wrong identifier (iPhone 5s, iOS 11) using ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"]

Tags: ios, swift, simulator

In Swift 4, I am getting wrong iOS Simulator identifier for iPhone 5s, iOS 11 using `ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"]`. It is returning iPhone6 instead of iPhone5.

Reference: [Detect Simulator iOS Version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30075200/7645247)

Comment: Try Out:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/6822622

Comment: The code he posted only says "Simulator". PS: I am trying to avoid third party library he mentioned.

Comment: This code works both simulator and iPhone. Plase at least read this code and condition. this is not third party

Comment: Nope, I tested his code and it does not work on simulator. On simulator it returns "Simulator", nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some research, I fount out that if iPhone6,1, iPhone6,2 is returning, it means iPhone 5s.