# Custom Font not working with size class

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode7

I am using a custom font and I want it to be customised using storyboard and size class. I want to vary it according to screen size of iPad and iPhone, smaller the screen size smaller the font size. But its not changing if I am using this custom font. I am using Xcode 7.

[image: I am trying to do it this way]

Comment: Show some code or some tries here we can not guess your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
class MyCustomLabel: UILabel {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.font = UIFont.init(name: “YourCustomFont", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
}
```

1. Now Just Change the font from storyboard from your current font to System Font. And select whatever font size you want to use.

[image]

Actually self.font.pointSize :- This will help you fetching the font size from the Storyboard (whatever you have set with System font.)

2. Just change the label class , and use MyCustomLabel in storyboard.
   Now run the application you will be able to see the changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Storyboard select the label you want to scale

Please find the below picture

[image]

[image]

More over from my point all of the iphone devices comes with quality pixels so this affect only a pinch level

you can't expect in ipone x -40size -> iphone 5 - 35size

but if your using device logic you can set whatever size you need to set for iphone 5 and iphone x

this will help you

[How to determine the current iPhone/device model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model)

use the link above and create extension then call the extension like below

```
modelName = UIDevice.current.modelName

switch modelName {
    case "iPhone SE" , "iPhone 5" , "iPhone 5c" , "iPhone 5s" :

        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name : "Vollkorn-Regular" , size : 20.0)
        name.font = UIFont(name : "OpenSans-SemiBold" , size : 12.0)

        print("i 5 series")
        break
    case "iPhone 8 Plus" :

        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name : "Vollkorn-Regular" , size : 24.0)
        name.font = UIFont(name : "OpenSans-SemiBold" , size : 16.0)

        print("i 8 series")
        break
    default:
        break
    }
```

Comment: so far you need to device logic which is quite simple

Answer (score 1):

You need a dynamic font size and width and for that you have to implement this two line of code -

```
labelName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
labelName.minimumScaleFactor = 0.3
```

And from your story board, change the lines of the label to 0-

[image] -

Or programmatically you can add this line of code -

```
labelName.numberOfLines = 0 // or you can set it 1 or 2
```

Comment: i want to change the font size. not number of lines

Comment: you are slightly right.but number of line 0 means you can add more than one line. And if you specify it by numberof lines 1 then what happened?. After one line your label will not show anything else.

Comment: labelName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
labelName.minimumScaleFactor = 0.3    ..this two line of code will change the font for different device