# How to determine the current iPhone/device model? while writing unit testcase

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, passkit

I have a method which returns Bool based on the PassKit. refer the below code:-

```
class func isHardwareSuportedForApplePay() -> Bool {
        return PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments()
    }
```

I need to write test case of above function. I think I need to check for the device. If device is later than iPhone 5 then it should be true. But **I don't know how to check device like. iPhone 5 and later.**
Please help.

Comment: Check the DeviceKit framework for testing device version and a number of other parameters: https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27759550/3418097

Comment: Check this link it has an answer of your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/563848
If your device has touchID as iphone-5 does not have.