# Is there any way to block device for a specific app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to install app in iPhone but when they click on app, than app give a popup to user **"App is not supported for your iPhone"** . it just like Whatsapp has blocked in many Devices Android as well as iPhones and Windows.

Please help me if any one have proper idea about it.

Comment: I believe that is because the OS would be lower than the supported OS. It doesn't have anything to do with the device i think.

Comment: Why do you want to block certain devices? Is it because of performance on older devices, or is there another reason?

Comment: It is depend on the OS version from which you give support to your app.

Answer (score -3):

It's **not** your responsibility to filter out devices. The most common approach is to set a `deployment target`. If you set your `deployment target` to `iOS 10`, users on `iOS 9`  (like the iPad 2) simply won't be able to download your app.

If you *really* want to block certain devices, you can always do it manually. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model) provides a way of getting the device model your app is running on. You can then manually check, like this:

```
if modelName == "iPhone 6" || modelName == "iPhone 6 Plus" {

     // Present a popup here.

} else {
     // Continue, because this device is supported.
}
```

Comment: No dud,  I am not satisfied with your answer.

Comment: @KumarLav Could you explain why? Your question is unclear and you refuse to be more precise, yet you're unsatisfied with my answer.

Comment: Apple would never accept an app that does what you propose in the 2nd half of this answer. If the app can be installed it must be allowed to run. Any valid solution must prevent the app from being installed (downloaded / purchased) at all.

Comment: @rmaddy While I do see your point, that’s not entirely true. Such “blocking” could be used for certain parts of an app. For example, certain features can be iPad-only. In addition to that, it’s also possible the OP is developing an in-house app. Your point is valid, but only in some cases.

Comment: But an iPad-only feature simply wouldn't appear on the iPhone. You wouldn't pop up an alert saying "Sorry, iPad-only". My real point is that Apple isn't going to allow an app that, upon launch, posts a blocking alert that says "Sorry, this device isn't supported". If a device isn't supported, setup the app so it can't be installed on the device at all.

Comment: @rmaddy And that is also not entirely true. While the OP asked about a popup, my code could also be used to hide features. I think the fault does not lie in my answer. The OP specifically asked about a popup, and I mentioned that’s not the way it usually works. BUT if, for some reason, he does want to go through with it, my answer will help achieving that.