# Check if headphone port is available in iPhone Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift4, headphones

I need to check if my iPhone has a headphone port or not. 
I checked if the headphone is connected using the following code

```
!AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.outputs.filter { $0.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.headphones }.isEmpty
```

But it shows me that headphone is connected or not. But iPhoneX does not have any earphone port.

> Is there any way to differentiate between "headphone not available"
>   and "headphone not connected"?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you make your check depending on device? like since iPhone 7 or later device there is no headphone jack

Answer (score 0):

You should not look for the feature. You should check the device model. Here you have a handy UIDevice extension to do that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/4076101

That way, if you get an iPhone 7(+) or posterior device, you can assure you won't have a headphone port (although you won't be able to know if a Lightning to 3,5mm adapter is connected.