# How to distinguish in code between the new iPadPro with a home bar and the old one with the home button?

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, ios12, ipad-3

I want to change constraints programmatically depending on whether the app is run on the old iPad Pro with home button, or the new one with the home bar (swiping indicator) (3rd generation iPad Pro). How can I make that distinction in Swift since they both have the same screen size - 12.9 inches. Is there some built-in flag?

I found the answer here by using the extension UIDevice:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/6217970

Comment: Just use the safeArea and you don't need to do any checking.

Comment: I want my view to cover the safe area and make the home bar (swiping indicator) look like its "floating", thus getting rid of the white line across the whole screen side. But if I do that then the view will be cut off for 20 pts on the iPads without the bar.