# Swift - Action based on different size devices

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, device

What I'm trying to achieve is to set different actions based on their device type.

So for example: If I want to do different stuff for an iPhone 8

```
if device type is = iPhone 8 
{

//action here
...

}
```

And so on for each device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the current iPhone/device model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
struct DeviceType {
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == 
    .phone 
    && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6S = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_7 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_8 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_X = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_XR = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0

    static let IS_IPAD = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH   == 1024.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && 
    ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1366.0
}
```

Comment: Please put the reference from where you copied the answer. Also copied answer misses `iPhone 11` series.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud use this library:

https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo

With this library you can write the code you asked for and you get tons of other features (obtaining device information) for free

```
if (deviceInfo.model == GBDeviceModeliPhone6) {
    print("It's an iPhone 6")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can do different stuff by using this below code by using it in your class so, you can set set action accordingly :=

```
    struct Device {
    // iDevice detection code
    static let IS_IPAD             = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
    static let IS_IPHONE           = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    static let IS_RETINA           = UIScreen.main.scale >= 2.0
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH        = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT       = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH   = Int( max(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH   = Int( min(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH  < 568
    static let IS_IPHONE_5         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568
    static let IS_IPHONE_6         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667
    static let IS_IPHONE_7         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667
    static let IS_IPHONE_8         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P        = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736
    static let IS_IPHONE_X         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812
    }
```

now you can set constrain like this:==

```
if(Device.IS_IPHONE_5 || Device.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS){
//--- set your constrain for iphone 5 and 4
}else if(Device.IS_IPAD){
//--- set your constrain for ipad
}else{
//--- set default constrain
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if UIDevice.current.deviceCategory() == .iPhoneX || UIDevice.current.deviceCategory() == .iPhoneXR {
  // Just this checking wherever you want  
}
```

Add extension below then use it.

```
extension UIDevice {

enum DeviceCategory  {

    case iPhone4
    case iPhone5
    case iPhone6
    case iPhone6Plus
    case iPhoneX
    case iPhoneXR
    case iPadPro12inch
    case iPad

}



func deviceCategory() -> DeviceCategory {

    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    switch height  {

    case 480:
        return .iPhone4
    case 568:
        return .iPhone5
    case 667:
        return .iPhone6
    case 736:
        return .iPhone6Plus
    case 812:
        return .iPhoneX
    case 896:
        return .iPhoneXR
    case 1366:
        return .iPadPro12inch
    default:
        return .iPad
    }
}
}
```