# iOS Launch Image for different devices/screens/resolutions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, screen

I faced such a problem.

My goal is to set for different devices(screen resolutions) different images that almost look like a main screen.

I went to `assets -> App icons & Launch Images -> New iOS Launch Image` and added for different iPhones different images. I also removed `Launch Screen File -> Launch Screen`. But i do not see anything on the Launch Screen. It is just empty. In previous versions of Xcode i have seen `Launch Image Source` but in mine (11.2.1) it does not exist.

Or maybe there is another option to set it?
I also tried to set `New Image Set` x2 and x3, but in this case any Plus version of iPhones use image for Xs Max/X Max Pro.

[image: Launch Image for different devices]

Comment: I would suggest using a launch storyboard instead of static images, as it will invoke auto layout etc.

Comment: i tried, but as i mentioned iPhone 6,7,8 Plus versions use same image (x3) as iphone XS MAX/MAX PRO. But they have different aspect ration.

Comment: In the launch storyboard, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model to detect the iPhone model and directly modify the UIImageView.image and .frame for different device models