# Roboto font is not working on iPhone XR in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I am new in swift I am trying to used Roboto font. Roboto font is working in iPhone 6s but it is not working in iPhone XR.
My Code is like this

```
    #ifndef DICE_PrefixHeader_pch
    #define DICE_PrefixHeader_pch  

    #define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    #define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    #define IS_IPHONE_4 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0)
    #define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0)
    #define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0)
    #define IS_IPHONE_6PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale] == 3.0f)
    #define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0)
    #define IS_IPHONE_X (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 812.0)
    #define IS_IPHONE_XR (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1792.0)

    GenralMethod.h

    +(UIFont*)setFont:(NSString*)fontName ForiPhone6Plus:(CGFloat)iPhone6Plus iPhone6:(CGFloat)iPhone6 iPhoneXR:(CGFloat)iPhoneXR andiPhone:(CGFloat)iPhone;

    GenralMethod.m

    +(UIFont*)setFont:(NSString*)fontName ForiPhone6Plus:(CGFloat)iPhone6Plus iPhone6:(CGFloat)iPhone6 iPhoneXR:(CGFloat)iPhoneXR andiPhone:(CGFloat)iPhone
    {
        return [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS?iPhone6Plus:IS_IPHONE_XR?iPhoneXR:IS_IPHONE_5?iPhone:iPhone6];
    }


    [btnMessage.titleLabel setFont:[GeneralMethod setFont:@"Roboto-Light" ForiPhone6Plus:20.0 iPhone6:20.0 iPhoneXR:20.0 andiPhone:15.0]];
```

[image]

I added it in storyboard also but its is not working in iPhone XR.

Answer (score 0):

Define device screen sizes by point rather than pixels.

This line will never get used.

```
#define IS_IPHONE_XR (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1792.0)
```

The iPhone XR has a screen size of 414×896 points (828×1792 pixels).

For a comprehensive list of all iPhone Screen sizes, look at this link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html

Comment: `+(UIFont*)setFont:(NSString*)fontName ForiPhone6Plus:(CGFloat)iPhone6Plus iPhone6:(CGFloat)iPhone6 iPhoneXR:(CGFloat)iPhoneXR andiPhone:(CGFloat)iPhone
    {
        return [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS?iPhone6Plus:IS_IPHONE_XR?iPhoneXR:IS_IPHONE_5?iPhone:iPhone6];
    }
` Maybe have a fallback or default value there, in case your iPhoneXR Dimensions are wrong. 1792.0 screen height seems a bit out of the ordinary. I assume thats why your XR does not load the font correctly.

Comment: its working fine in iPhone 6s but not in iPhone XR.I have done all the process. Just not understanding why this is happing

Comment: The iPhone XR has a screen size of 414×896 points (828×1792 pixels). You need to go by the points not by the pixels

Comment: @Mujtaba Edited my answer, please have a look and adjust your code accordingly. Should work then ;)

Comment: Change code but nothing change still the problem is same

Answer (score 0):

To answer why it doesn't work, it's because you've specified the wrong screen height. Replace your `#define IS_IPHONE_XR` definition with:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_XR (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 896.0) //896 seems to be the height after testing
```

and it should work.

But, why define macros and perform checks with hardcoded display height values when you could do better approaches like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/9293498 to know the device model? I strongly recommend this approach to be more generic...

Comment: Change code accordingly but still the problem is same

Comment: You've tried the alternative approach, or changed the hardcoded value?? Would be better if you can share what exactly you've changed...