# Constraint to the top of the screen above the notch iphoneX

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

[image][image]

I want my button to be 20pts from the left and 20pts from the top. It looks great on the iphones prior to the notch. How can I constraint this button to the top of the screen? So it will look symmetrical from the left and top. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can wire your button from the top with `superView` not safe area.
you can do this by clicking on the top constraint for the button, and from the inspect menu on the right on Xcode change the second item to `superView`

Comment: do not forget to update your constraint constant after doing this

Comment: can you please share a screenshot?

Comment: i added it to the post

Comment: `So it will look symmetrical from the left and top.`, if you set pts 20 both left and top then it conflicts with time at the top left on the screen

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: it is better to display components within `safeArea` of the screen with align top and leading to safe Area

Comment: so can I set a different constraint for iphonex phones

Comment: I think I got the problem, you may check for top Constraint for the super view of Label. i.e. the view which contain your label. it may still wired to SafeArea, it should be wired to super view as well @Captaionddfsdf

Comment: you can add constraint to iPhoneX only, but it is bad Idea.
but briefly, you can do this as the following.
1- you need to check your device model, you can do this using extension in this like 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model
2- you add your constraint programmatically.

but I do not recommend this solution. it is not a good practice @Captaionddfsdf