# Make iOS app only available to devices with LIDAR?

Tags: ios, lidar

I'm developing an app that uses recent device LIDAR capability - how can I make that app ONLY available to recent iPad Pro's and iPhone Pro's with LIDAR hardware?

Comment: Not possible. You can only limit via iOS version.

Comment: However you can check if the device support LIDAR using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383288/check-if-ios-device-has-lidar-in-swift