# How to programmatically check if the iPhone/iPad device has a TrueDepth Camera?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, xamarin

I am working on a 3D Scanning app and I created the test extension below in order to check if my user's device has a TrueDepth camera. Currently I have a problem in my app where I have to keep changing the list of compatible devices [from Apple's Docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209183) and keep updating the reflection switch-cases [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/11104068).

```
static let hasTrueDepthCamera: Bool = {
    let authContext = LAContext()
    let _ = authContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil)
    return authContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.faceID;
}()
```

I was wondering if the extension will work even if the user's FaceId is not setup in their settings, or will it return false?
Unfortunately, I am not able to test it on my phone because it will remove all the cards from my account wallet.

Comment: To use the extension it is needed to setup faceID in settings, unless you will not get the faceId , check https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208114.

Comment: Are you using ARKit?

Comment: No I’m just using the standard cyborg SDK @yuchen

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to detect if the device has **TrueDepth** Camera or not, is to check if the device supports face tracking or not, using **ARkit's** `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`.
You can use following code to detect if the device support face tracking.

```
guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else {
  fatalError("Error: This device model does not support face tracking")
}
```

Comment: Yes; I think this is the most confident way to make sure True depth is available. This also checks that device has a proper chip to run true depth features

Comment: this won't work because this returns true after ARkit4 even if device does not support true depth

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this directly with `AVFoundation` (which is most likely how frameworks like ARKit go about it).

Here's a Swift sample code:

```swift
let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInTrueDepthCamera], mediaType: .depthData, position: .front)
guard let depthDevice = discoverySession.devices.first else {
    print("Your device does not have a TrueDepth front camera")
    return
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer because newer ipads that have touch id but no true depth camera will return true if you only check ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported