# SwiftUI: How to make a universal view for one iphone model

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am creating an app using custom vibrations. I want to use custom vibrations made by CHHapticEngine but it doesn't work on iPhone 6s. I don't want to do everything in AudioToolBox because it doesn't have that complex options to do. So my idea is to create some kind of exception just for the iPhone 6s. Maybe some kind of checker if is iPhone 6s do it in less complex version or maybe you know a better way to make it work. Please help.

Comment: Is your question how to conditionally display a view based on the model of the device?

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I was looking for. Could you please tell me do I have to delete this question or close it somehow? I am new to it.