# How to detect user's device has dynamic island in UIKit?

Tags: swift, uikit, dynamic-island

In my application, I was implemented **pull-to-refresh** feature and custom loading icon. In IPhone which has **dynamic island**, It was overlapsed my loading icon.

I want to detect device which has dynamic island or not. If it has, I will add some top space to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, as far as I know, **dynamic island** is will included in `ActivityKit` on late of 2022. You can check from [this link for ActivityKit](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=hi37aek8) and [Apple's thread about it](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713978). And Apple doesn't provide way to check dynamic island is on device or not.

But there is a workaround for you to get the thing you want. Currently **dynamic island** only available on `iPhone 14 Pro` and `iPhone 14 Pro Max`. So just need to check this both device.

**Update**: Thanks to [this link for type model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model/26962452?answertab=trending#tab-top), name model type of `iPhone 14 Pro` and `iPhone 14 Pro Max` is `iPhone15,2` and `iPhone15,3` so we just need to check these case.

Code will be like this

```swift
extension UIDevice {
    func checkIfHasDynamicIsland() -> Bool {
        if let simulatorModelIdentifier = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
            let nameSimulator = simulatorModelIdentifier
            return nameSimulator == "iPhone15,2" || nameSimulator == "iPhone15,3" ? true : false
        }
        
        var sysinfo = utsname()
        uname(&sysinfo) // ignore return value
        let name =  String(bytes: Data(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, count: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN)), encoding: .ascii)!.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)
        return name == "iPhone15,2" || name == "iPhone15,3" ? true : false
    }
}
```

Usage

```swift
let value = UIDevice().checkIfHasDynamicIsland()
print("value: ", value)
```

Comment: According to Apple documentation, the name is a generic device name on iOS 16: "iPhone", and the user's assigned name in older versions. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620015-name?language=objc
Neither will be useful for this purpose. For how to really find the iPhone model, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/908621

Comment: This does not support iPhone 15 & later versions...

Comment: Dear @Ahmadreza, when will iphone 15 release or there is another way to achieve I will update the answer

Answer (score 11):

1. According to the live activity documentation, we can only detect whether the device supports **Live activity**, but we don't know if the device has **dynamic island**
2. I use the window `safeAreaInsets` value to detect **dynamic island**. when the device orientation is **portrait**,  `safeAreaInsets.top` is equal to `59`(Display Zoom Default),
   or `51`(Display Zoom Large Text).
3. This is likely to support the iPhone15 Pro/iPhone15 Pro Max and later models.

usage: `print(UIDevice.current.hasDynamicIsland)`

```
extension UIDevice {
    
    // Get this value after sceneDidBecomeActive
    var hasDynamicIsland: Bool {
        // 1. dynamicIsland only support iPhone
        guard userInterfaceIdiom == .phone else {
            return false
        }
               
        // 2. Get key window, working after sceneDidBecomeActive
        guard let window = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.flatMap { $0.windows }.first { $0.isKeyWindow}) else {
            print("Do not found key window")
            return false
        }
       
        // 3.It works properly when the device orientation is portrait
        return window.safeAreaInsets.top >= 51
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this with multiple different devices to make sure there is no conflict with other sizes and they all worked, this is a more future-proof solution for now.

Comment: add +1 checker for code:
```
// 0. iOS 15+
guard #available(iOS 15.0, *) else {
    // Code for earlier iOS versions
    return false
}
```