# Warning with 'init(validatingUTF8:)' in Swift

Tags: swift, compiler-warnings

I'm working with a piece of Swift code ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234519/12035498)) that takes a `modelCode` and checks against a `modelMap` dictionary to get a model. When the model is a simulator, it checks the simulator's model identifier. Here's my code:

```swift
guard let mcode = modelCode, let map = String(validatingUTF8: mcode), let model = modelMap[map] else { return Model.unrecognized }
if model == .simulator {
    if let simModelCode = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
        if let simMap = String(validatingUTF8: simModelCode), let simModel = modelMap[simMap] {
            return simModel
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler is showing a warning:

> 'init(validatingUTF8:)' is deprecated: Use a copy of the String argument

[image: Deprecation info in documentation]

How can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 0):

The warning you're seeing is because the method `init(validatingUTF8:)` for `String` has been deprecated in newer versions of Swift. Instead of using this initializer, you can directly use the `String` value.

Here's a refactored version of your code that avoids the deprecated method:

```swift
guard let mcode = modelCode, let model = modelMap[mcode] else { return Model.unrecognized }
if model == .simulator {
    if let simModelCode = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"], let simModel = modelMap[simModelCode] {
        return simModel
    }
}
```

In this revision, I directly used `mcode` and `simModelCode` as keys for accessing values from the `modelMap` since they're already of type `String`, thereby removing the need for the deprecated initializer. This not only resolves the warning but also makes the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Strange, the [documetation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(validatingutf8:)-208fn) says nothing about the method being deprecated. _Edit:_ If I take the sample code from the documentation and run it in an Xcode 15 playground I do _not_ get any warning about it being deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added the deprecation info as image from the Swift.String framework to the question, but you're right, there is no deprecation info in the [web documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(validatingutf8:)-208fn).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(validatingutf8:)-8awk3

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks, this is so confusing :) I see that the documentation in Xcode  says deprecated as well so I guess that's where you should first look.